# How do I remove HTC Desire pre-installed Android applications?

Tags: applications, internal-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)

My HTC Desire from Orange came with a number of pre-installed demo applications and games, these cannot be removed normally from the application settings or from the market place.

What is the best way I can remove them and free up the space for applications I actually want?

Answer (score 19):

Generally the only way to remove these manufacturer-added apps is to root the phone.

Comment: Yes, Al is correct.

Comment: What does rooting mean?

Comment: @Dan: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236/what-does-to-root-a-phone-mean

Comment: I've rooted my Desire HD but still can't uninstall stuff :-(

Answer (score 1):

Root your phone first, then use Root Uninstaller to remove all the bloatware. This is similar to another question Acer Liquid, but there Root uninstaller was not successful, but on my lg p500 it wokred perfectly. SO try it.

Answer (score 0):

Other way could be to get a generic image for your phone and flash it. The Problem with that is that such a image is mostly not available in the net.