# Remove bloatware from Acer Liquid Mini (E310)

Tags: uninstallation, bloatware

I am trying to remove Apps installed from phone vendor, like docs to go, without success.
I have read [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor) and similar topics and I have tried the Titanium Backup Chuck Norris mode but somehow documents to go appears again at reboot.
I tried to find a custom rom but for this phone it looks like there is no one.
Or maybe I wasn t great at searching...
How can I get rid of documents to go forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing a different rom simply did the job.

Right now I'm using 2.3.5

Unfortunately I just have guides in Italian and French but a little google translator did the job :)

French:

http://www.acer-club.fr/viewtopic.php?f=98&t=3336&sid=64e715b102a9932965fa871175c01da9

Italian:

http://www.androidiani.com/forum/modding-acer-liquid-mini/80562-guida-installare-android-2-3-5-su-acer-liquid-mini-custom-rom.html

Comment: Maybe you want to tell use which ROM it now is for you Liquid Mini?

Comment: I've edited the post :)

Answer (score 0):

Root the phone and download root uninstaller, once you grant root access to the app you will be able to remove all the bloatware.

Comment: Does this work where Titanium fails? I somehow doubt it.

Comment: I've not used Titanium, but every single bloatware was removed from my phone with root uninstaller.

Comment: I have no trouble removing with titanium but as soon as I reboot everything is back in place

Comment: just try using this and let me know what happens !

Comment: No luck... same problem... at reboot everything is back :(

Comment: ahh, that is surprising, it works perfectly for me ! Has your phone been rooted properly ?