# How do you remove locked apps without rooting? With Android SDK?

Tags: uninstallation, bloatware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)

I really don't want to root my phone. It works fine as is, except for having the extra unwated apps.

Can one remove unwanted pre-installed apps on a non-rooted phone?