# How can I deal with unwanted system applications without rooting?

Tags: applications, uninstallation, system

There are a lot of system apps in my mobile that I do not use, and have no intention of ever using. I know that is is possible to [uninstall system apps and bloatware with root](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor), but is it possible without root?

Are there any non-root options that will help me to deal with unwanted system applications?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, that is impossible -- as only root can make the system partition writable (which is required to delete a system app, which is stored there). However, using ICS (Android 4.0) or above, you can at least "freeze" them (make it "invisible and unusable") -- and, if you later decide otherwise, also unfreeze them again (see e.g. [How to Remove / Disable the Bloatware Apps in the HTC One X](http://androidadvices.com/remove-disable-bloatware-apps-htc/) or [Bye-bye, bloatware: Disable system apps in Android Ice Cream Sandwich](https://blogs.computerworld.com/article/2471733/mobile-apps/bye-bye--bloatware--disable-system-apps-in-android-ice-cream-sandwich.html)).

Answer (score 10):

I agree with Izzy's answer mostly, however *technically* it is possible to do so without.

Background:

- System apps reside at /system/app/*
- /system is a separate partition that is mounted read-only during normal use
- Some phones (HTC) even lock the flash partition to disallow any write
- Normally one gains root on the normal system to make /system writeable and remove stuff with root rights there
- Rooting is the process of becoming root on the normal Android system and make this persistent by installing some file (/usr/xbin/su and such)

To remove apps without rooting one would have to not root his phone but find another means to remove unneeded apps from /system

- On Google Nexus devices one would unlock and boot a temporary custom recovery to do that (no rooting of the normal Android instance)
- With Samsung devices one could use the same approach like CF-Root does (download partition, modify, write back)
- Or just run an exploit withouth the rooting procedure afterwards and use that temporary root to do all needed cleanup

Bottom line: Rooting and then doing it is far easier. I just wanted to explain that it is indeed possible technically

Comment: Can you tell about doing it for Samsung (Galaxy Y) in a little more detail, or may be provide a link?

Comment: I have no links, sorry. I'd say the easiest way to do it is root/remove-junk/unroot [see here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1611830). If you really would like to do it without rooting: You can see the contents of unroot.zip and create your own *update.zip* that removes just what you don't like. However: You need to learn how to do it and how the scripting works, **but** beware of the risks: You could easily break your phone. Better root+unroot afterwards, it's a known path.

Comment: Just thinking out loud here; but wouldn't you be able to connect your phone to a Linux computer, and mount the `/system` partition from there?

Comment: No. The block dev for /system cannot be accessed via USB  mass storage without having root. Also regular linuxes don't support yaffs2 out of the box.