# Removing stock browser on Jelly Bean

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.1-jelly-bean, stock-browser, chrome-for-android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unistall a system app without root?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26632/unistall-a-system-app-without-root)

Chrome is the default on Jelly Bean OS. When I bought Nexus 7 tablet it came preinstalled with JB, but when my Galaxy Nexus got upped the old stock browser is still present.

**How can I get rid of the stock browser on Galaxy Nexus in JB?** Is it at all possible?

Comment: You'd basically do the same thing as if you were removing carrier bloatware (see [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor) and [Unistall a system app without root?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26632/unistall-a-system-app-without-root))

Comment: @eldarerathis: Actually your second link really helped me. I removed **stock browser** from JB, **Email** (that's used for exchange), **Exchange services** and **News & Weather**. Put your comment as an answer and I'l accept it. Don't know why you haven't done so in the first place anyway? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not really remove the app from your device, but "freezes" it (i.e. makes it "hidden", so it no longer shows up in your App Drawer etc.):

From your Homescreen, open the menu and go to *Settings → Apps → Browser*, and there hit *Disable*.

If you later decide you want it back: Same path, and *Enable* it again.

Comment: Be sure to install Chrome first, so that you actually have a browser...

Comment: @MichaelHampton: No worries about that. I have Chrome and Firefox as well. Although not liking any of these on GNex. Chrome on Nex7 is **very** similar to desktop experience and I like it lots!