# How to delete a system app?

Tags: applications, 2.3-gingerbread, uninstallation

How can I delete any system app? I deleted a wallpaper app in my app folder but I don't see any changes? I want to delete some apps especially default factory-installed apps. Is there a simple way?

Comment: [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)

Comment: [How can I deal with unwanted system applications without rooting?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26632/how-can-i-deal-with-unwanted-system-applications-without-rooting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are rooted, then you can delete or hide them with the Titanium Backup app, but if you aren't rooted, I don't think there is a way to delete the system apps.

Comment: I'm rooted and I have full access.

Comment: Try just uninstalling the app from the app drawer, but if that doesn't work, you can disable, hide, or fully delete apps by installing [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5rZXJhbWlkYXMuVGl0YW5pdW1CYWNrdXAiXQ..)

Comment: Before uninstalling any system app, I strongly recommend to freeze it for a few days to see if nothing else depends on it. Then make sure to back it up (Titanium Backup is a very good choice for that) before you finally delete it. And keep in mind, you don't gain any additional space by deleting it (as it resides in system space, where user-installed apps have no access to).

Comment: But I'm root  can I delete all file from app folder?

Comment: I honestly don't remember. When I run a custom ROM I got rid of the bloatware anyways. That's why I told you to try it and then use Titanium Backup if it doesn't work that easily.

Answer (score 2):

**Root:**
You can install [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to uninstall unwanted apps [easily](http://www.guidingtech.com/13523/freeze-uninstall-android-system-apps-titanium-backup/).

**Without Root:**
I found an interesting article which helps you creating a script to remove certain stock APK files.
Check it out [here](http://droidviews.com/2013/easily-remove-stock-appsbloatware-from-your-android-phone-without-rooting-it/).

1. Download the recovery flashable BloatKill script in `zip`. Do not
   extract it: [bloatkill.zip](http://d-h.st/BFI).
2. Download and install a zip manager program on your computer, such as
   WinRAR or PowerArchiver.
3. Double click the `bloatkill.zip` to open the `zip`
4. Now browse over to `META-INF\com\google\android\`
5. Right click the `updater-script` file and extract the file to
   desktop. You can also extract this file by dragging it to the
   desktop.
6. Open the file with a suitable program like NotePad++, or Adobe
   Dreamweaver. The opened script file should look like this:

```
ui_print("Unwanted stock apps remover.");

ui_print(" ");
ui_print("Partitions mount");
#Properly unmounting to avoid issues
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "umount", "/system");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "umount", "/cache");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "umount", "/data");
#Then mounting
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "mount", "/system");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "mount", "/cache");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "mount", "/data");

ui_print(" ");
ui_print("Unwanted stock apps remover");
delete("/system/app/StockApp.apk");

ui_print(" ");
ui_print("Unmounting partitions");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "umount", "/system");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "umount", "/cache");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "umount", "/data");

ui_print(" ");
ui_print("Finish");
```

The line `delete("/system/app/StockApp.apk");` being the app you want to delete.

1. When the editing is over, save the changes and exit NotePad++ or the
       editor you are using.
2. Now drag the `updater-script` file back to its place:
   `META-INF\com\google\android\` folder in `bloatkill.zip`
3. Now copy the `bloatkill.zip` file to the root/main directory of your
   phone’s SD card (`/sdcard/`)
4. Open phone Settings and enable `USB Debugging Mode` from `Developer
    Options`.
5. Turn off your device and boot it into `Recovery Mode`. The method
    involves a special combination of hardware keys that are pressed
    simultaneously and differ from device to device.
6. In the recovery mode use the volume keys to scroll/highlight and
    the power key to select an option.
7. Scroll to an option called `apply zip from sd card` and select the
    `bloatkill.zip` file.
8. Confirm your choice by selecting `yes`.
9. Finally, select `reboot system now`.

Answer (score 0):

you can not uninstalled them if not rooted,but you can disable some of them.not all!
go to Setting --> application manager --> then select application that want disable --> and disable it