# Disabling System Apps that have been updated and User apps [No Root]

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, applications, disable-app

How can I disable system apps that have been updated through the Play Store without doing "Uninstall Updates"?

For instance, Maps is a system app, which has been updated. How can I disable it without uninstalling the updates?

I would also like to know how to "Disable" User Apps, without Root!

My device is a Sony Xperia U.

Comment: Can you explain *disable it without uninstalling the updates*?

Comment: Easy: He wants to keep the currently installed version, but freeze it -- so he might "unfreeze" when he really needs it. A quite common requirement for Google Maps; I do that with TiBu, but that requires root. Without root, via *Settings->Apps*, it seems one has to "uninstall updates" before one is able to freeze a system app.

Comment: [How can I deal with unwanted system applications without rooting?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/26632) seems relevant.

Comment: My vote is for eldarerathis's answer, if you have 4.x then you can just disable it in the apps section in the settings. No way around the un installing updates option [unless you root], sorry

Comment: Would also help if we knew what device it was for, i.e. if you have a nexus you could boot a custom recovery flash the most up to date gapps then reboot, staying unrooted but with up to date apps