# want to remove Samsung Apps

Tags: updates, uninstallation, samsung-apps

I don't need poor Samsung apps such as *SamsungApps, Chat-On, Blurb, S-Translate* anymore. Can i simply uninstall them and make an exclusion in my Updates so as not to get them back again?

Comment: Please see: [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6851/16575) / [How can I deal with unwanted system applications without rooting?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/26632/16575)

Answer (score 3):

You can remove them, you just need to root your device and then download titanium backup and you will be able to clean them out completely!

1) How to root your phone? Depends on your device!

2) Stop updates? Go to apps, find samsung apps and there you have an option to specify when to update them! Choose none and you are good to go.

Comment: Correct. Alternatively, swap your Samsung phone for a Google Play Edition S4 (or similar), which comes with no manufacturer bloat.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove those apps normally.

What you can do is - disable them, at least you won't be getting annoying notifications.

Open **Application Manager** -> **All** -> **ChatON** and click on **Disable**

*If you really want to purge them. You have to **root** your device.*