# Uninstall the applications provided by the company

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, uninstallation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)

I am using the [LG P500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LG_Optimus_One#Primary_configuration) phone, running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread).

I want to uninstall the applications provided by the operating system distribution, that is, the default applications. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System apps are stored in the `/system/` partition. You can only uninstall them if your device is rooted (see: *[How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device)*).

Preinstalled software are most likely system apps, so if you can't uninstall them through the *Settings* menu there is probably no other way than rooting.

Comment: Suppose one roots one's device and then uninstalls a few applications. Now after uninstalling can he "unroot" his device and go back to using the standard OS again?

Comment: Yes it's possible to unroot.