# How do I uninstall a system app with root?

Tags: root-access, uninstallation

Have root. Tried "autorun manager" app which gives option to  display system apps & uninstall, but still said "uninstall not successful"

Comment: We already have this question multiple times, including answers. You might want to take a look at e.g. [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor), or check the [questions tagged bloatware](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bloatware).

Answer (score 1):

I quickly read the description of [Autorun Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun), and it doesn't mention the ability to uninstall system apps, but there are several apps that can do this, for example [Root Uninstaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.free). Do a search on the Play Store for "root uninstall" for more.

Answer (score 0):

If you already own a copy of Titanium Backup you can uninstall a system app with this tool too.
Anyway Root Uninstaller mentioned by onik seems to be free and therefore cheaper as Titanium Backup Pro (if you haven't already bought it).