# Samsung WhatsOn Video won't unintsall/disable

Tags: samsung, bloatware

I tried to uninstall/disable it but the "Disable" and "Show notifications" are greyed out -- I have not rooted phone. I am running Android 4.2.2 on a GT-19205 Mega. Note that the normal "Whatson" app can (and is) disabled.

Anything I can do to get ride of that annoying bloatware?

Anyone?  There's a bounty and all that...

Comment: This sometimes happens after OS upgrades (e.g. 4.2.1 -> 4.2.2)  Try resetting the preferences by going to Settings -> Apps -> Menu -> Reset app preferences.  Keep in mind that this will re-enable any apps that you've previously disabled.

Comment: @Chahk: Yes, it did re-enable everything but WhatsOn Video is still in the same state :(

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the software? If it's to regain some storage, that's probably not going to work. If it is because of a service running in the background, you can try stopping the service, but even if that works, it has to be done at least once every time the phone boots. If you want to get rid of the software so it won't show in the app drawer, you can remove the icon from the drawer. Not sure if it can be done with the Samsung drawer, but in a lot of other homescreen apps you can (Like Nova, Apex,Action Launcher etc..)

Comment: @user1261104: I should be able to get rid of it regardless of reasons.

Comment: Usually this kind of bloatware problem can be fixed by flashing a custom ROM, but it might reset all files and data you have. For the meantime, maybe you can follow [this advice](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor). (btw, there is a confusing statement on your question: "no **non** rooted", rooted or not?)

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks for the comments and link.  I shall investigate.