# Editing the apps within factory reset

Tags: factory-reset, hard-reset

Much like flashing a new custom Rom that's been de bloated, there are some factory apps, and some are stripped. My question is, can you edit the apps that are within the factory reset? So when you DO factory reset, the modified apps that you changed will be the apps replaced into the system, and not the plethora of useless bloatware.

Comment: Haven't understood what you mean by editing apps but factory reset implies setting the  cell to the condition it was in when you purchased the cell  bloatware and  all

Comment: What I seek is to modify the apps themselves within the factory reset, allowing me to factory reset to a de-bloated state.

Comment: Ah understand.  Answer is same. Factory reset brings the phone to the condition it was in when it was bought. What you are trying to do requires root and custom recovery like  TWRP or  CWM which makes a nandroid copy and restores exactly to that state.  If  this answers you let me know so that it can be upgraded to answer

Comment: Somewhat, but the answer is not quite satisfactory. If the device pulls a list of predefined apps to reinstall upon a factory reset, then there must be a way to modify that list of apps.

Comment: Then you are looking at  modifying recovery image built into the phone and I am yet to  hear  a way of it being done and IMO is  not possible

Comment: This isn't satisfactory, I have root on all of my devices, there isn't anything that I can't modify. I understand what you are telling me, but I am certain there is definitely a way.

Comment: Understand your point.  Let's wait for a knowledgeable person to show how it can be done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)

Answer (score 0):

Well, why not?

Whenever you write a change, such as a modified or deleted app, to `/system`, which is where most factory bloatware resides, it cannot be reversed by a simple factory reset. Why?

A factory reset just does a perfunctory wipe of `/data` and `/cache`. This removes any user-specific info done after the initial configuration, as well as user-installed apps. This does not affect the system partition in any way, so any changes made there will persist after a factory reset is done.

My recommendation:

1) Take a NANDroid backup.

2) Delete whatever you need to from `/system`.

3) That's it, its not coming back even if you do a factory reset. Now, if you need to restore the backup, that's a whole different story.