# uninstall preloaded apps on intex aqua power II

Tags: stock-android, bloatware

i currently use the intex aqua power 2 smart phone with android 5.0 . There is a bunch of preloaded apps on it and i want to remove them . How to do it?

Comment: **Root** your phone and delete the applications from /system/app or /system/priv-app. If no root is available for your device (which is the case here I think) then you can try to disable the apps from settings->applications-> select application you wish to deactivate and deactivate it.

Comment: @benjaminS anything i need to be wary of

Comment: @user3594202 Don't delete apps you don't know.

Comment: Always 1) make a backup first 2) only freeze apps (to figure if they're really not needed) 3) delete only after steps 1+2 had positive results :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)

Answer (score 0):

Its just a cake walk I'll prefer to use kingRoot apk which can be downloaded by searching in Google and then root your phone using it which need internet connectivity and then it creates an app named King user in that you can see an Option as uninstall Tool which can be used to uninstall the bloatwares and just restart after uninstall to get rid of completely its Completely trustable as i done it in my Phone Micromax A106 contact me if you need more any clarifications :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Root your phone.
2. Enable USB debugging mode.
3. Download [debloatware](http://rootjunkysdl.com/?device=Android%20Programs&folder=DeBloater) tool from XDA Develpers.
4. Open up the tools and select the application in the Tools.
5. Tool will backup the application and remove it or hide it.