# Remove swisscom on Samsung s6

Tags: samsung

I ordered a Samsung s6 from some shitty page on the internet, I got the phone and it's the real Samsung s6 but they put some shit called Swisscom in it, which is really annoying cause the phone starts up with the Swisscom. How do I remove the whole Swisscom shit? 
Please answer!!! Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)

Comment: I voted the question assuming that "Swisscom" is an app. [This suggested edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/126799) contradicts my assumption. So, what is this "Swisscom" and how is it annoying for you?

Comment: @Melinda Have your factory reseted

Comment: So I found that Swisscom sells Samsung GS6 ([link to its product page](https://www.swisscom.ch/de/privatkunden/produkte/samsung-galaxy-s6(N_NATEL%20RES%20plus%20XL,24,000000000010234605).html)). Now, what do you want to remove, exactly? Boot animation? (and remember, don't beg for answer, it's *rude*)

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways that you can do it. 
If you want to remove just the application you can use system app [remover](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp&hl=en)
2:To change/remove carrier(swisscom) splash screen form s6
Re-flash your phone using the official [firmwares](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6).
How to flash a new [firmware](http://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool)?

Comment: We're looking for detailed answers here. Please see [how do I write a good answer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and [edit] your answer to incorporate the required steps.

Comment: beeshyams i updated the link thanks. @Firelord i do respect you man but the thing is you don't answer any question and interfere without any effort- about the detailed answers you must know this is not a teaching website its a problem solving, asking questions, getting the hints-make it work.

Comment: I won't be defending myself on what I post or what efforts I put since that wouldn't raise the quality of your answer. // I'd say your opinion about this site contradicts with mine. Unlike what you opine, I want this site to be the final place where a reader should be looking for an answer. In accordance with that, I post comments wherever I think proper instructions are lacking. There is more: hints work for those who can understand them. There is no evidence in the question that OP understands how flashing works or has ever done that, so definitely instructions are needed.

Comment: I won't be barring myself from posting such comments again, so if you find them annoying or you think your opinion is the correct opinion how the answers should be, please sort that out on [meta]. If other users agree with your opinion, I would consider that as the final word. Thanks!

Comment: I understand your point and I respect it everyone here have a right to speak their mind. but as far my answer goes instead of writing long notes I prefer to point out certain things and link them to their actual pages so the user can understand them much clearer, but hey its all my point of view.