# How to uninstall a system app using adb uninstall command (NOT remove via rm or any other way)

Tags: adb, twrp, uninstallation, miui, supersu

Have to mention this to avoid possible confusion, this question is *not* duplicate. This question is specific to **using adb to uninstall a package**. There are several similar questions but are all different from this one, as they're focused on removing an application by any means.

*Please do not provide answers using "rm" command to delete the package files. Also, answers related to malformed package names, or trailing carriage returns. I think they're pretty much all covered in all the other questions.*

I had `pm uninstall` functionality but after ROM upgrade. Some things won't uninstall anymore. For example the following two system apps (which I removed under previous ROM, significantly improving overall performance):
/system/priv-app/SecurityCenter/SecurityCenter.apk=com.miui.securitycenter

/system/app/Updater/Updater.apk=com.android.updater

Now I get an error trying to pm uninstall them:  **Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]**

But other **system** apps (which won't uninstall through regular android interface) do uninstall via `pm uninstall` command. Example:
/system/priv-app/Browser/Browser.apk=com.android.browser

So both are system apps, what could be the difference between them?

For reference, I upgraded from MIUI 8.1.6.0 to 8.5.3.0, and re-installed TWRP and SuperSU. This question is not specific to my ROM, as I see other people are in the same situation. But I seem to have an advantage being able to be able to uninstall some system apps. And am willing to contribute, to find a solution for everyone, to uninstall any app.

I tried: mount -o rw,remount /system
but that didn't solve it.

Please help out with any ideas along the way. Thanks!

---

*`Update 1`*  - Confirming steps to avoid intermittent issues

 * Wiped all partitions in TWRP 

 * Installed Latest ROM (MIUI 8.5.3.0)

 * Went back to TWRP, wiped only /Data

 * Restored /Data from backed up version of the ROM that came with device (MIUI 8.1.6.0)

 * Now after I boot into OS, ROM shows as latest (MIUI 8.5.3.0) in settings

Now I am able to pm uninstall every app I've tried. Even the most resilient: Google APP, Updater, Security.

This Frankenstein.. err I mean hybrid ROM works fine so far, and I've already removed many system packages, making the phone (Redmi 3S+) visibly faster. But I would still like to pinpoint what was causing this to make it into *Generic Solution*. So, if it ain't broke I'm willing break it, so next time it breaks we will know what's causing it and how to fix it.

*`Update 2`*  - 

 * Wiped all partitions and restored all partitions from Original ROM. 
 * Restored to factory settings (using TWRP) 

 * and after booting into ROM, went back to TWRP and made another backup

 * Using same scenario as in Update 1 above, with only exception of using /Data from here. pm uninstall does *not* work.

Any thoughts on the differences between the two /Data partitions I should be focusing on?

Comment: AFAIK `pm uninstall` cannot be used with system apps. As it's not clear whether you really want to *uninstall* or simply to *hide* an app (you mentioned `pm disable`), could `pm hide` be what you're really after?

Comment: @Izzy Yes it can. That's what I'm saying above, I just edited/made it a bit clearer. I want to *pm uninstall* but what I meant was, before upgrading, I could do both, uninstall and disable on System apps, even wrote nice scripts to take care of everything after upgrade.

Comment: I have **never** succeeded with `pm uninstall` on system apps. But I have a guess: Is your previous ROM an "engineering" build? I suppose it works with an eng build (aka dev build).

Comment: @iBug no, actually previous ROM was the one that this phone came with. The new ROM is also an official upgrade from manufacturer's site.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43673368/4720957 // And, can you pastebin the content of these two files: `/data/system/device_policies.xml` and `/data/system/device_owner.xml`?

Comment: @Firelord My MIUI Optiomization setting was already _off_. device_owner.xml is absent. device_policies.xml just has these lines: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?> <policies setup-complete="true"> <active-password -stuff here- /> </policies>

Answer (score 26):

I succeded adding the **-k** and **--user** options to the **pm** command, e.g.:

```
pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.service
```

The command was issued as root, no need to remount /system as rw. Android on the phone is 6.0 and the package is a system app. Without the extra option I get the error:

```
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]
```

Comment: Thank you. For anyone else reading, some guides have a single dash in front of the user, which was causing the error for me.

Comment: Note: -k is not needed. Guides on the internet do copy-paste blindly. -k is to keep app data intact. 9/10 if you are removing bloat, you should not care for preserving the app's data. No need for that flag.

Comment: for me it worked using: `adb shell cmd package uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.service`

Answer (score 15):

Also works without -k (keep user settings) option:

```
pm uninstall --user 0 com.android.service
```

and without opening adb shell:

```
adb uninstall --user 0 com.android.service
```

Comment: upgraded from miui 10 to miui 11. but for few system/priv-app these cammands fail. eg  for com.miui.calculator