# Low disk storage Space, 47G is used by Bixby Vision

Tags: internal-storage, disk-drive, samsung-bixby

I started getting low disk space a week ago, everyday I clean up cache and data from Apps, even uninstalling apps, but still get the space issue again after a few hours.

I download DiskUsage app and I found that "Vision Provider" is using 47G (Picture attached), I never used Bixby so I'm not sure why it's taking all this space.

How can I delete the Vision provider to free disk space?

[image]

Comment: You can try disabling that app. If there is no such option, you can [remove it](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/179575/96277) which would work until you factory reset the device. In any case, make sure to backup important data as I don't know how your phone would react if that app is disabled or removed.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is resolved now, I needed to clear the data of Bixby Vision, that freed 55G+.

Comment: Alexa Alice Bixby Cortana Google Siri, 55 Gb scares me a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to clear Bixby Vision data:
Settings -> App Info -> Bixby Vision -> Storage -> Delete Data