# Deleting the security app in miui?

Tags: xiaomi, miui, delete, bloatware

Read contradicting things about deleting that bloatware default security app (redmi note 8 pro). Some say its safe to do so but others say its tied down to some core system functionalities. Has anyone tried it? Thanks.

Comment: Deleting a system app can cause many problems! And talking about security app in MIUI then why do want to delete it in the first place? It's not a bloatware either!

Comment: If you delete it then you won't be able to give permissions to apps that requires like display over other apps etc.

Comment: Let me share an example. I have a Lenovo tablet and it's very old so in order to delete some bloatware I rooted it and then deleted hangout, Google Play music , etc apps and after reboot for every tap on screen I got some app failure error. Now you can see deleting some minor apps caused this problem and you want to delete a major MIUI app.

Comment: The app is good in many ways: 1. If install an APK and it has some even minor sort of virus then it won't get installed due to this apps virus protection software. 2. You are running out of soace then just click on cleaner it will help you delete your cache. 3. Many apps running in background and consuming a lot of battery then just click battery& performance and problem solved. 4. Phone running slow then click optimize and boost.

Comment: Also if you are thinking to use external virus protection software like Quick Heal, etc then it won't work in MIUI ROMS(both stock and custom) due to heavy customisation of MIUI ROMs. **Try installing external virus protection software and check it for a week** you will understand the problem.

Comment: SecurityCenter.apk can not be disabled/frozen from adb shell, you will end up in boot loop [How can the SecurityCenter.apk be disabled/uninstalled safely?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/179575)