# Can I disable Passpoint somewhere on the OS level (not GUI)

Tags: adb, wi-fi, aosp

I'm using a version of Android for the Raspberry Pi and PasspointManager is causing the machine to crash and go into an endless boot loop.  Is there any suggestion for a way to disable Passpoint on the machine altogether?  A solution for any version above 10 and ideally 12 would be very helpful.  There is no menu option to disable Passpoint as on some devices.

The fact that it's a Raspberry Pi is not relevant other than to any other users with a similar issue, this is an AOSP question.  The following instructions are added in AOSP with no additional info on where to make the alterations within WifiManager:

"Conversely if device implementations do not include support for Wi-Fi Passpoint:

[C-2-1] The implementation of the Passpoint related WifiManager APIs MUST throw an UnsupportedOperationException."

Comment: I'm not sure if Raspberry Pi is critical to the issue (like, if there's a specialized Android ROM for RaspPi while this community might not have experience with that), but just FYI, we also have a sister site [raspberrypi.se].

Comment: Could probably be done via [tag:adb], if you've enabled that (see our [adb tag-wiki](/tags/adb/info)) and know the package name. There are multiple ways to either disable (see e.g. [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56620/16575) or even remove (see e.g. [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/179575/16575)) the app.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Izzy!  I will look into that and report back if I find anything useful.