# Turn off emergency call quick access while the switch to turn it off is disabled

Tags: settings, emergency-calls

My Realme X2 (Android 11) phone, being a little old, when I press the power button, it gets pressed multiple times. I know this is a hardware issue, but I'd still like to get rid of emergency calls.

The disable app option is disabled and removing permissions does nothing.

| [image] | [image: 2] |
| --- | --- |

Is there any way I can do it with ADB? I'm not planning on rooting this one yet.

Comment: I didn't find a solution, but things got annoying, so I rooted and reverted to Android 10. Victory is mine! :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking for a better solution for this myself, for now, the best I could do (on Android 13) was change the number it calls.  For me, emergency # is 911, so I changed this to just "0".  So even if it triggers accidentally, at least it doesn't call an actual "911" number.

Comment: You can remap the power button only after rooting or even just delete the emergency SOS app. Apart from these, I don't see a way out.

Comment: I found an alternative solution using ADB from Reddit. Could you try it and let me know if it works?

Answer (score 0):

For Realme devices, according to multiple Reddit users on [r/Realme - Emergency SOS](https://www.reddit.com/r/Realme/comments/okshpx/emergency_sos/), the Emergency SOS app can be disabled by using ADB without the need for rooting:

```
adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.oppo.sos
adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.oplus.sos
```

(the package name should be either one of them depending on the device model)

Comment: I'm willing to, but you'll have to bring the instructions down a few steps .. what's adb? where I get that? how to run this command line on phone/app ??

Comment: @Ditto It is an interface to communicate with your device. Android Debugging Bridge. Watch any video out there, you will get it.  BTW Andrew, you wrote `pm uninstall` instead of `pm disable`. People have been trying to do what your typo suggests for ages haha

Comment: @44yu5h I usually hear about `pm uninstall` instead of `pm disable`, as also mentioned in [How to uninstall a system app using `adb uninstall` command (NOT remove via `rm` or any other way)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/179575/44325)