# Lollipop - disable certain background process

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, background-process

I have an old (but rooted) phone running Android 5.1.1 (Lollipop).

I realized it runs many background processes which I absolutely don't need.

I can stop them manually via `Settings > Apps > Background processes`, however I wish to keep them disabled: they slow down the cold-start of the phone which I don't like.

So I'm looking for a way to not just disable but completely ban certain processes (i.e. ban them from starting).

How can I do this on these old versions of Android? Unfortunately Google is quite blurry and noisy for these search terms.

Comment: Are they `init` services, system apps, or user apps? See details [here](https://mirfatif.github.io/IAnswers/view_android_background_services.html). How do you know they are not needed?

Comment: A solution is to reduce the number of installed apps.

Comment: System apps: like Google Photos+, or Google News, etc.

Comment: @RohitGupta: how can I uninstall System apps? :)

Comment: @Daniel if you want to uninstall system apps, you can try [`pm uninstall`](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/179575/44325) command.