# Delete inbuilt apps completely after rooting

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-on7

I have a Samsung Galaxy on7, running on Android 6.0.1.

It has a lot of pre installed apps that I consider bloatware. I want to remove them completely from the phone.

Recently, I tried removing these apps as per this video:

[Video 1](https://youtu.be/fAqmjU_EJ8g)

But soon I found that it does not delete the system files, because that is not possible without root.

I also found that I can root my phone using adb. The procedure (on a different phone, though) is here:

[Video 2](https://youtu.be/wsjQkQKWMFg)

After rooting and installing magisk, I want to delete the system files from adb using the following command (say, to remove google photos):

```
adb shell rm -f /system/app/Photos/Photos.apk
```

and

```
adb shell rm -f /data/user/0/com.Google.android.apps.photos
```

Two questions on this:

1. Is this possible to be done on my device? Any precautions?
2. Is there any way to backup the system files before deleting it?

Comment: Get Titanium Backup. You can backup and delete anything then as long as you have root.

Comment: Be aware that in modern devices it is often better to disable the apps than to remove them. Removing system apps will not gain you any storage space and could cause a huge issue if you ever attempt to take an OTA update in the future.

Comment: Firelord recently wrote how to uninstall apps for a specific user (see [here](/a/182123/16575) and the command with `--user`). Maybe that's a road to investigate. But as @acejavelin wrote: try disabling the app first and watch out for side-effects. Always easier to re-enable than to re-install ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)