# Delete programs pre-installed on Samsung Galaxy 551

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-551, bloatware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)

How can I delete some programs that are pre-installer on my phone?
On settings I can't delete them, is there a way to delete those?

I'll use it focused on development.

It has some samsung applications that I'll never use.

It comes with Android 2.2

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35/how-do-you-remove-pre-installed-apps-on-a-rooted-phone and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/834/how-do-i-remove-htc-desire-pre-installed-android-applications