# How to get permission for overwrite files in /system/fonts directory in Android phone

Tags: file-permissions

I'm tryng to overwrite the fonts files (*.ttf) in my android device (Dell Aero). my new fonts are resident in the sdcard and I'm using the following command in a command shell (on the phone):

cd /sdcard/MyFonts/
cp *.ttf /system/fonts/

I get a "permission denied" echo from the cp command.

How should I do it correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to *root* your phone first, and probably set it *S-OFF* to be able to write to the `/system` directory while booted.

---

See [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236/what-does-to-root-a-phone-mean) for information on what rooting is.  *S-OFF* is the next step that gives you full control all of the time.  Neither are something you should do without understanding the risks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I'm a beginner in Android so can you please explain what the meaning of root the phone and set it as S-OFF? also, how shall I do it?