# What is rooting?

Tags: rooting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does “to root a phone” mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236/what-does-to-root-a-phone-mean)

Is rooting just copying `su` onto the phone?  Does it try to get the root user's password?