# How can I fix Xperia x10i application crashes under CyanogenMOD 6?

Tags: applications, reboot, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10, crashes, force-close

I have a lot of issues with my Xperia x10i:

- I get a lot of forced close of apps
- I don't have zoom in my camera nor flash light
- I don't have Mediascape nor Timescape and maybe other apps I don't know about
- From time to time it reboots from its own
- My music app dosnt work
- My camera doesnt work in apps (like Goggles or Barcode Scanner), it just gives me colorful stripes and no picture

As far as I know Sony has only released Android 2.1 for this phone and doesn't plan to do 2.2, But I noticed (in the info tab section) that my phone is 2.2.1! It seems that it was rooted and had Cyanogenmod 6 installed.

Please help me fix my issues.

i also have several question to understand a bit more :
  is my phone rooted? and what does it mean exactly? 
  and if i do this would i still have Cyanogenmod? can i get back after that (i like its features)?
  and what does rom and mod mean?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a specific question here? "Please help me with my problems" is not a specific question. If there really are that many problems with it you may need to break this up into several questions.

Comment: the question is how to fix  these problems..i think they r related so its better to put them in the same post..if not just let me know,its my first post here

Comment: We prefer questions that have the potential for a single answer. Except for "you got scammed" I don't think there might be a single answer here.

Comment: im getting some ideas here then i will be able to ask specific questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it :)

in case somebody is in the same situation, here is what i did:
i flashed my phone to its original rom using [flashtool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=920746)  (if u dont know how to use it go [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=928343) )

thats it

thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend going back to the Sony official firmware.

[This thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1054818) has step-by-step instructions for reverting Xperia X10 handsets to stock ROM.  You might want to search the thread to confirm that the process is the same for your X10i model before starting.

Keep in mind that flashing to the stock firmware will erase all of your settings and installed apps, so back up the important bits.

Comment: already did,but didnt change anything..but will take a look at the thread maybe there is a method more efficent,thx

Comment: can i ask plz, is my phone rooted? and what does it mean exactly? and if i do this would i still have Cyanogenmod? can i get back after that?

Comment: If your phone has a custom ROM installed, then it's definitely rooted (see here for explanation: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236/what-does-to-root-a-phone-mean). If you revert to official firmware, you will no longer have CyanogenMod.  Yes, you can always re-root the phone and install a custom ROM if you wish.

Comment: thx,if i re-root it,would i get these problems again?cause from what i understand they were caused by rooting..

Comment: Most likely rooting itself did not cause any of these problems, but installing a custom ROM could have.  For someone that is new to Android and is not technical enough to troubleshoot these issues on their own, I would highly recommend **not** installing a custom ROM.

Comment: Cyanogenmod is a custom rom right? what do i have to do to get technical enough? i dont know tutorials about this or any usefull resources..

Comment: Yes, CyanogenMod is a custom ROM.  http://cyanogenmod.com is a good starting point.  You should be familiar with some Linux terminology, and be comfortable with using the Command Line.  Keep in mind that installing a custom ROM is a fairly technical process, and if not done correctly can render your phone useless.  It will definitely void any warranty on your handset.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to start your phone in recovery mode (download and install quickboot from market).
If your phone restart in recovery mode you just need to find the last version of cyanogen working on your phone, install it and live happily.

If you don't feel like it just do a wipe all from your recovery menu (that's a complete "format" of your phone) and install from scratch latest sony firmware from their website.

As you start in one path or another and face different problems just come here with new and more accurate questions so we can give accurate answers :)

You'll get a brand new phone: do not give up!

Comment: Pitto,thank you for ur answer, i dont give up :)  
i installed quickboot and restart in recovery (i didnt notice any change!) but then i didnt know how to find the last version of cyanogen.   
i intsalled rom manager to try to do that,but updating the rom is only for premium users!

Comment: if you didn't see any change I think that you have no recovery installed :/
Hurry then:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=859571

Comment: Here you find information about installing the roma again :)

http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/install-custom-cyanogenmod-6-1-1-rom-on-sony-ericsson-xperia-x10/

Comment: i tried doing what the link said,i installed busybox...then my phone is booting againa and again!!!dont know what to do!