# Wallpaper on Kindle Fire

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire, wallpaper

I want to get rid of ads on my Kindle Fire and set some of my pics as my wallpaper without rooting it. Is this possible and how do I do it? I keep looking at different sites but none helps. Any advice?

Comment: [What does "to root a phone" mean?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236/what-does-to-root-a-phone-mean)

Comment: As far as I know, Amazon offers you to remove the ads for a certain fee (don't remember how much it was). And wallpapers you can always set as you wish, root or not.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't change the lock screen wallpaper.

If you want to turn off the ads, go to [Manage Your Devices](https://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/fiona/manage#manageDevices), and edit your special offers subscription status.