# Is it possible to share WiFi network (not 3G network) via BT PAN to other devices?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, bluetooth-tethering

I'm tring the BT PAN profile on an Android 4.1 device.
There is no 3G network on my device.
I use Wi-Fi to connect to the network.

Is it possible to share the network from my device by BT connection?

Thanks,
Cliff

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully done this in the past using [Wifi Tether for Root Users](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/) - it has an option to leave the WiFi on during BT tethering. But it needs a [rooted](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236/what-does-to-root-a-phone-mean) device.