# I am having Xolo Play smartphone. I want to support it Gujarati Font. How can I do that?

Tags: fonts

I am using smartphone xolo play.
I tried to download the gujarati font library to support Gujarati Font. But not able to achieve it.
So please guide me how can I support Gujarati font in my xolo play smart phone.
Thanks in advance.
Bskania.

Comment: Same as with most other fonts I'd say. Have you checked the [corresponding questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts?sort=frequent)? There are even some posts [specifically to Gujarati](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=gujarati).

Answer (score 0):

Root the mobile first. Then install the app "Font  Installer" from Play Store. Download some Gujarathi font, keep it in SDCard and install through Font Installer app.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a font of the regional language you will first need to Root your device.

Follow [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236/what-does-to-root-a-phone-mean)  in order to understand what does rooting a device mean and this question on how to [root](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device).There is one more [site](http://androidxda.com/root-xolo-play-t1000) which is providing rooting specific to your device

1. After you have rooted the device then you need a file manager
   application like ES [file Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)
2. Now download the  [font
   file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/hq6cdpppdoh1gvq/DroidSansFallback.zip)
3. Open Es file explorer (give root access open the file
   explorer>Config > Give root access)
4. Copy your font file and paste it to (Root)/System/Fonts
5. Set permissions as 644 or RW.
6. Reebot/Restart your device.
   Now if you want to give gujrati as the input font download the keyboard app from the play store.

**Rooting your device will void your warranty and you will be doing on your own risk. Please understand the risk's or data loss involved and go ahead only when you have the complete knowledge of it.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Gujarati fonts package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gujarati-fonts-package/) addon to view Gujarati webpages without any other installation on Firefox for Android.

Comment: That wouldn't provide system-wide support for the font, would it?