# Need help rooting my phone

Tags: rooting

I have a Micromax Canvas spark 2 q334 running android 5.1 and it has a very low internal storage.so I need to root my phone to use link2sd. some guides suggest Kingroot but it doesn't work for my phone..also there is no custom recovery available for my phone so I couldn't root using recovery method.can someone guide me on how to root my phone.

Comment: Visit [Help center](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge accounts

Answer (score 0):

You could try other one click root apps like Vroot or frama etc.

"Very low internal storage" you could be more specific, 8/4 MB?

Answer (score 0):

Try searching this site and XDA for general information. Your mediatek device may have an unlockable bootloader (try fastboot oem unlock) . Or you might have a root ADB shell (try adb shell+adb root). These methods require the ADK.

If you are lucky your manufacturer has added a root setting in your phone (maybe under developer options).

Failing  that you can either create your own custom recovery and try flashing that, OR modify the stock ROM and flash that using your PC. These (riskier) methods require your understanding of SP flashtool software.

All these methods require you installing the device drivers first.

See also [What is rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236/what-does-to-root-a-phone-mean) and [How do I root?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device?lq=1)