# What Exactly is this *expletive* Rooting Business?

Tags: rooting

Sorry this is a rant. I'm using the file manager EX Explorer and i just want to create a folder, put some files in it, possibly rename the files. Why did i have to spend 4 hours going through youtube videos and forums talking about "rooting" and "rooting directory". It is the simplest process imaginable...just moving files into folder. I'm NOT touching any system files. Why do i need extra or to enable permissions? I don't understand. Just what exactly is this rooting business anyway? In the end i just followed the "hint" and selected each directory i needed for each file, a long laborious process. Why hasn't android addressed this seemingly silly and extremely frustrating issue?

Comment: This is not a place to rant. If you have a specific question, go ahead and ask. You don't need to root your phone in order to move folders. If you want to know how to move files, first search the site to see if your question was asked before. If it wasn't, go ahead and ask your specific question. -1

Comment: *What* files are you trying to move and *from where to where*? Specific folders are locked down by the OS to prevent tampering with system files.

Comment: Also, look at this thread: https://www.android.stackexchange.com/questions/236/what-does-to-root-a-phone-mean for more info on rooting a phone.

Answer (score 2):

There's 2 parts to your question:

- **What is rooting:** On Linux-based systems (like Android) the "admin" user, i.e. the user with complete access to the entire system is called the "root" user. Since this is a potentially dangerous thing, the "root" account is often disabled. "Rooting" your phone is a term used to describe the procedure that either re-enables this "root" account or gives you (the owner of the phone) "root" privileges.
- **Why do you need to root your phone:** Well, long story short, it's your phone, you should have full access to it, shouldn't you? Most phones come bloated with apps that you do not need but cannot be uninstalled unless you have "root" privileges. If only for that, you should have "root" access so you can uninstall those nuisance apps and free-up some memory, storage and battery power.