# How to restart an Android device?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, reboot

Is there a way to restart an Android device? Now I have to shut it down and manually turn it on again, but I'm looking for a solution where the whole process happens automatically.

This might be device specific, mine is Samsung Galaxy S.

Comment: Good question, my galaxy s doesn't have a menu option for that and I couldn't find an application to do that.

Comment: A quick way for any phone is remove the battery cover and remove the battery. I have noticed that works on any phone.

Comment: @abhi: How is that quicker or more convenient than just turning the thing off and back on again?

Comment: @AlEverett my phone gets stuck sometimes and no matter how long I press the power button, nothing happens. So I slide open the cover, remove the battery and pop it back in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The menu you get when you press the power button should give you a list of options including Shutdown, Restart etc. If it doesn't, your phone's manufacturer might have left it out of the ROM.

Comment: Ok. So it seems that it's left out from Galaxy S :(

Comment: I can confirm that. On my Galaxy S I have: Silent Mode, Flight Mode and Power Off.

Comment: I don't know that any manufacturers included "Restart" in the menu when pressing the power button. I've only heard of that in custom ROMs.

Comment: @AlEverett I've always had 'Reboot' in my HTC Hero ROM. The only difference that CM made, for me, was that when I chose Restart, I could choose between 'Reboot', 'Recovery' and 'Bootloader'. It could depend on manufacturer, model or (in the US) carrier.

Comment: Is the "shutdown key" the same as the power button?  Pressing and holding the power button (for ~2 seconds, with my FairPhone) should bring up the Shutdown/Restart/... menu.

Comment: I'd also like to know what "the shutdown key" is.  I wonder if @Tobias resolved this after commenting?

Answer (score 11):

Use the app **[Quick Boot](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.siriusapplications.quickboot)** to restart your device (a rooted device).

Answer seems to be given partially here:
[I've rooted my phone.  Now what?  What do I gain from rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1/ive-rooted-my-phone-now-what)

Use the app Quick Boot to restart your device. Start the Quick boot app and choose 'Reboot' and there you go.

Comment: In case it's not clear, Quick Boot requires root.

Answer (score 4):

Press (volume up + Power) at the same time. It will reboot the phone. Tested on Galaxy S Captivate.

Answer (score 4):

The volume up + power option also works for the Samsung Galaxy S. You have to hold for about 10 seconds before restart, but it works.

Comment: Works also on my SGS! But it puts the ringer volume to maximum too and that seems to stay at maximum after the reboot :)

Comment: The correct way to reboot in Samsung Galaxy S is to hold home button and power button pressed until the phone reboots.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, for the Samsung Galaxy S 4G just hold the power button for ten seconds and it will restart.

Comment: Does it restart normally or just force shutdown?

Comment: @roxan it's a forced shutdown that doesn't go through any of the normal shutdown tasks, effectively the same as just pulling the battery out while its running.

Comment: So I assume this is not correct answer. Forced shutdown under normal condition can corrupt data.

Comment: huh... that's weird... it doesn't force shutdown on mine... its about the equivalent of telling it from the adb commandline to reboot... the only other way I've seen to reboot it is to root the phone and download an app that reboots it and I'd rather not void my warranty by rooting. Because all the methods listed above do about the same thing as pressing the power off button and holding it...

Answer (score 1):

just found out with my galaxy y. hold Home button first, then hold Power button. just continue holding these buttons for a few seconds and the phone will restart itself. :D

Comment: This works with Samsung Galaxy S as well, at least with Gingerbread.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way no one has mentioned yet (for rooted devices):
Use a shell application [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot) or [SL4A](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) and type:

```
$ su
# reboot
```

It will reboot instantly. With SL4A you can create a .sh script and add a shortcut to your home, something like `su -c "reboot"` would do the job, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

@jadkik94, what you say is kind of true, it is true that you need root to use the reboot command INSIDE adb shell. Although! You can use **"adb reboot"** without needing root ;) this is a small trick that you have to know

same counts for

```
adb reboot recovery
adb reboot download
adb reboot bootloader
```

**So no root is needed to restart the device (when you have your pc with you)**

If you run windows you could also use my little tool called Android Reboot

[image]

Instructions:

1. Put your phone on debugging mode: Settings > Applications > Development (GB)
2. Put your phone on debugging mode: Settings > Developer Options (ICS and UP)
3. Connect your phone with the usb cable to the computer
4. Choose one of the options

Download:
http://broodplank.net/files/AndroidReboot_v1.1.rar

Answer (score 0):

For my FairPhone (first edition, FP1, Android 4.2.2), it's pressing and holding the power button for about 2 seconds. This brings up a little menu which offers to switch off, restart (both after an additional prompt), or toggle flight mode.

I suppose this is a common Android feature (because it is described in a beginners's guide to Android smartphones I bought), and thus should at least work for all Nexus devices as well.