# How to reboot an android device without using power button?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s, reboot

Unfortunately, the power button doesn't work and I'm not able to power off the device.

The only way, is physically pull out the battery, but if I'll do so, I wont be able to power it on again.

The cellular network doesn't work , and the Wi-Fi seems to, too.

The device is up for 53:21:59 hours!! (and seems to count..)

I must force somehow a reboot.

Is there shell command (and if so - how to access it?) , or application that forcing reboot?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions in [How to restart an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/how-to-restart-an-android-device) Is your device rooted?

Comment: @eldarerathis My device is not rooted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can connect using adb (usb debugging), you can simply use the command "reboot".

If you're rooted and have a terminal emulator installed, "su reboot" will do the same thing.

The reboot command will also accept arguments of "recovery" or "bootloader", which will reboot you into the recovery or bootloader respectively.

Comment: Hell! Now it works -- after I took half an hour to find you the perfect work-around *LOL* Better this way, of course :)

Comment: There is also a way to do a "soft-reboot" (AKA "quick/fast-reboot"). I think it's by using busybox. However, I can't find how to do it. Do you know how?

Comment: @androiddeveloper While you probably would've found a way, for other readers: the soft-reboot can be done using the command [`killall zygote`](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/82857/96277) or for Lollipop, the graceful one  -- `am restart`. Both needs root access.

Answer (score 4):

### Widgets/Apps which might help (also with other phones)

Take a look at [Fast Reboot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greatbytes.fastreboot). The app claims to work on non-rooted devices (*Does NOT require root!*). Trouble is, this doesn't perform a *full reboot*, but just "kills all processes" to simulate a fast boot (I guess this includes the "system server", so it comes very close to a reboot).

Another "app" you could give a try is [Simple Reboot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=simple.reboot.com). It doesn't mention root anywhere in its description, but claims to be a shortcut to the boot option. Not tested, but it *might* do for you.

### Secret Codes / Service Menus

Almost all real-boot solutions seem to require root, so it will be hard to find anything suitable. BUT: It could be that one of the built-in service menus offers an option to (re)boot the device. You can invoke them via your dialer program, entering a "magic number". Examples would include:

- `*#*#197328640#*#*` (one of the service menus)
- `*#*#4636#*#*` (or `*#*#INFO#*#*`) System information (this one should work on all phones, and for sure gives you useful system information. I cannot remember if it had a reboot option as well -- but it cannot hurt to know this code ;)
- `*#7465625#` (miscellaneous service options related to the SIM, AFAIR, and coming from a Samsung Galaxy list)
- Heh! Look at this: **`#*2562#` = Restarts Phone.** (Source: [Galaxy S Secret Codes](http://samsunggalaxysforums.com/showthread.php/4701-Galaxy-S-i9100-Secret-Codes))

There you go! Last option should be the easiest one -- no additional tools needed. If it works. Not having any Samsung device, I cannot test...

Comment: [Simple Reboot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=simple.reboot.com), considering the ever changing Android, needs root as of now.

Comment: Yeah, looks like every new Android version brings us new feature (restrictions). So now it even reached reboot? How long until we need root to silence the device, or allowing it basic operations? :(

Answer (score 1):

I found only one app to reboot WITHOUT root.

[Real Reboot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.anothermobile.realreboot)

On my phone (Nexus 4) that is working, but only if you do not have the newest Android OS.

Comment: It's description  now says "*You can select different reboot methods. All Android Versions from 4.2.2 or higher need root!!!*"