# What's the best way to restart Android via command line (remotely)?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, reboot, shell, command-line

I'm looking for the best / friendliest way to reboot my rooted android 4.1.1 device. I found these solutions so far:

- `su -c "reboot"` - Causes problems with wifi after restart on my device... I read that this can cause a currupt file system in some cases... Doesn't work via ssh for me.
- `toolbox reboot` - Same concerns here, but works via ssh.
- `reboot -d 8 -f` - causes problems after restart e.g. some apps wont start
- `busybox killall system_server` - "Hot Reboot" (not really a system restart)
- `start|stop` - Starts/stops Android Runtime (not really a system restart)

What is the device doing exactly when I'm pushing the (hardware) power button? I guess that's the most friendly way.

Comment: `su -c "reboot"` runs the `reboot` command, which is defined in `reboot.c`.  `reboot.c` hasn't changed much over the years.  It has always called [sync()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sync) and then rebooted the device.   Also, thanks to [this commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/e3aeeb4de34dbb93e832e6554f494122ba633f3b), modern versions of `reboot.c` also unmount all filesystems.  Android 4.1.1 includes the commit I mentioned, and so I don't see how `su -c "reboot"` on Android 4.1.1 could ever cause filesystem corruption.

Comment: Dear acy:  Firelord's late answer (`su -c 'am start -a android.intent.action.REBOOT'`) works for me on Android 4.1.2, and seems to me to be the best of the existing answers.  If it works for you on Android 4.1.1, or if you're too busy to try it, please click the green checkmark in order to make it float to the top of the answer section.

Answer (score 17):

> What is the device doing exactly when I'm pushing the (hardware) power button? I guess that's the most friendly way.

You get to see a dialog with an option to power off the device (stock Android doesn't offer reboot). It appears that [ShutdownActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.1.1_r1/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#1723) is called upon when you long press Power button.

Anyhow, this is what you can try, remotely or locally, but only with root access:

```
su -c 'am start -a android.intent.action.REBOOT'
```

It will do a graceful shutdown followed by the reboot. I was looking for an intent when I noticed it [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/bad80e0dccdeaeea97991f7d092678ff0df1bc84/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#1689).

Method is tested on Android 4.2.1, 5.0.2 and 6.0.1 and [should work for Android 4.1.1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.1.1_r1/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#1723) as well

### Update

Tested on stock Android 5.0 and 6.0.1:

```
su -c 'svc power reboot'
```

Per the source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/cmds/svc/src/com/android/commands/svc/PowerCommand.java#40), KitKat builds should also support the command.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I still do find it odd that it says "Powering off..." when there are values for the reboot text.

Answer (score 14):

Simple, really:

- Android is safely shutting down vital parts of the runtime.
- The OS is also broadcasting intents to tell apps and services to gracefully close. These, in turn, flush their caches of all data and shared preferences, save what-nots to the sqlite database, et cetera.

In other words, apps and services are given a chance to do their cleanup systematically.

The commands that you have tried are harsher. They actually bypass the safety mechanisms for a graceful shutdown.

Android is not Linux per se, in the sense of an ordinary desktop version of Linux where those commands could be issued to shutdown the Linux environment.

It might be possible to create a wrapper script such as this:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
am broadcast android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN
sleep 5
reboot
```

You could save this as `safe_shutdown.sh`, with permissions of 0755.  Your mileage may vary, depending on handsets and ROMs — so no guarantees there.

Comment: thanks for this explination! is it possible to do this remotely e.g. via ssh (not adb)?

Comment: I think he want's to know how he can mimic the button shutdown with a command.

Comment: if that's the friendliest/safest/best way to shut down the device, then yes :)

Comment: @Flow `adb reboot`? I am not certain if that's safe!?! Maybe a wrapper script around it to send a broadcast `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` then call `adb reboot`?

Comment: Not sure broadcasting`ACTION_SHUTDOWN` will do what you want either: ["Apps will not normally need to handle this, since the foreground activity will be paused as well."](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN)  Sounds like most apps therefore *won't* handle it.  Is pausing the activity sufficient?

Comment: How can you pause the activity then? Its not a guaranteed spot to save preferences etc as per the activity lifecycle. Not alone that, the script would end up getting convoluted in determining which apps are running, including services... did not see that bit about `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` (it was true for older versions but was changed slightly in JB)..

Comment: @sguha Try something like this via ssh: 
`su -c 'am broadcast android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN && sleep 5 && toolbox reboot'` (May vary depending on your ROM)

Comment: Looks like none of these work on my devices. Tried it on FinlessROM running on RK3188 device as well as LG P970 with CM10.1.

Comment: still experiencing network issues here after rebooting via command line (tried _su -c 'am broadcast android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN && sleep 5 && toolbox reboot'_ and _busybox killall system_server_)

Comment: `am broadcast android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN` seems to broadcast the intent fine on my Android 5.1.1 "Lollipop" emulator.  It returns:  `Broadcast completed: result=0`.  Oddly, the same command never returns anything on my Samsung Galaxy S Relay running Android 4.1.2 "Jelly Bean". Instead, the `am` command seems to just keep running forever.

Answer (score 11):

```
killall zygote
```

This will kill the root `zygote` process and cause a Android system refresh.

This does not restart your phone's hardware, only the Android processes.

By default (in Linux), the `kill`/`killall` commands do give the processes a graceful way to shut down, though it depends on the *zygote* implementation whether this in turn gracefully shuts down your running Android apps.

Note: you must run this as root, whether you use `su -c`, connect via SSH or ADB, or another method.

Other names for this action:

- soft reboot
- hot reboot

Comment: I have noticed on some devices, the Wifi will not reconnect properly after this command (so I have to disable the Wifi, wait a minute, and then re-enable the Wifi again).

Comment: For readers: In Lollipop, the standard way to restart the Android framework is `am restart`. This requires root access though.

Comment: Does `killall zygote` give processes a graceful way to shut down?  Interesting question.  Someone would have to look at the `zygote` source code in order to know.