# How can I execute a Tasker reboot command only 1 time?

Tags: boot-loop, reboot, tasker

I'm working with a chinese tablet which needs to be initialized every time after it's connected to a power source.

I'm using [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) to do so.
Problem is: this condition makes tasker execute the `reboot` command over and over, and it becomes a *bootloop*.

What should I do in order to initialize the tablet when a power source is attached, but avoid it from entering the *bootloop*?

Edit: TaskerProfile

```
<TaskerData sr="" dvi="1" tv="4.6u3">
<Profile sr="prof2" ve="2">
<cdate>1431370575080</cdate>
<edate>1431372456863</edate>
<id>2</id>
<mid0>4</mid0>
<State sr="con0" ve="2">
<code>10</code>
<pin>true</pin>
<Int sr="arg0" val="1"/>
</State>
</Profile>
<Profile sr="prof5" ve="2">
<cdate>1431370730220</cdate>
<edate>1431371684461</edate>
<flags>2</flags>
<id>5</id>
<mid0>6</mid0>
<State sr="con0" ve="2">
<code>10</code>
<Int sr="arg0" val="1"/>
</State>
</Profile>
<Project sr="proj0" ve="2">
<cdate>1431027887676</cdate>
<mdate>1431371133517</mdate>
<name>Base</name>
<pids>2,5</pids>
<tids>4,6,7</tids>
<Img sr="icon" ve="2">
<nme>hl_aaa_ext_home</nme>
</Img>
</Project>
<Task sr="task4">
<cdate>1431370589904</cdate>
<edate>1431372085383</edate>
<id>4</id>
<nme>Task1</nme>
<pri>10</pri>
<Action sr="act0" ve="7">
<code>410</code>
<Str sr="arg0" ve="3">Documents/sdcard.txt</Str>
<Str sr="arg1" ve="3">0</Str>
<Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
<Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
</Action>
</Task>
<Task sr="task6">
<cdate>1431370741046</cdate>
<edate>1431372415674</edate>
<id>6</id>
<nme>Task2</nme>
<pri>10</pri>
<Action sr="act0" ve="7">
<code>417</code>
<Str sr="arg0" ve="3">Documents/sdcard.txt</Str>
<Str sr="arg1" ve="3">%True</Str>
</Action>
<Action sr="act1" ve="7">
<code>410</code>
<Str sr="arg0" ve="3">Documents/sdcard.txt</Str>
<Str sr="arg1" ve="3">1</Str>
<Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
<Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
<ConditionList sr="if">
<Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
<lhs>%True</lhs>
<op>2</op>
<rhs>0</rhs>
</Condition>
</ConditionList>
</Action>
</Task>
<Task sr="task7">
<cdate>1431371028431</cdate>
<edate>1431372348654</edate>
<id>7</id>
<nme>runshell</nme>
<pri>10</pri>
<Action sr="act0" ve="7">
<code>123</code>
<Str sr="arg0" ve="3">reboot</Str>
<Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
<Int sr="arg2" val="1"/>
<Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
<Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
<Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
<ConditionList sr="if">
<Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
<lhs>%True</lhs>
<op>2</op>
<rhs>0</rhs>
</Condition>
</ConditionList>
</Action>
</Task>
</TaskerData>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to connect the device to a power source which triggers [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to reboot the device (for initialization). But when the device reboots itself [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) finds that the power source is connected so it repeats the task again. Your goal is to make [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) reboot only once while power source remains connected. If the source is to be removed and re-inserted again, then [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) should do the reboot again only for once.

---

Based on this understanding, I proposed the following solution:

The solution is very trivial. I'm using two profiles in [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), namely:

1. Not power USB
2. Power USB

These two profiles, as obvious, will be triggered by connecting/disconnecting the power source to the Android device. I'm using a file's content as a condition here to restrict boot-loop.

<sup>Note: For this answer, I chose my power source as USB only.</sup>

#### **Instructions**:

**Regarding the file content:**

1. Create an empty file in your default storage. (I created a file named `sdcard.txt` in `/sdcard`. The location of this file is `/sdcard/sdcard.txt`.)
2. Open this file in a text editor in Android and add `0` in it. (I used [920 Text Editor](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.jecelyin.editor)).
3. Note that there is no logical reasoning in using `0` only. It will be used in a conditional statement only. You're at liberty to try an another number.

**Regarding Profiles and Tasks in [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) app:**

1. Launch [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm).
2. Under **Profiles** tab create a **Profile** by tapping `+` → **State → Power → Power**.
3. Under **Source** choose **USB**.
4. Check **Invert** -- this will make **Not power USB** profile.
5. Press Back key/button once and select **New Task**.
6. Add a name for your task (persistent) or leave it blank (deleting profile will delete it as well).
7. Under **Tasks** tab tap `+` → **File** → **Write File**.
8. Under **File** field mention the location of your text file. In this case, it is `/sdcard/sdcard.txt`.
9. Write `0` under **Text** field.
10. Uncheck **Append**  and **Add Newline**. -- we want to replace the content, so no appending should be done.
11. Tap Back key/button twice to save this task.
12. In order to create **Power USB** profile, repeat step 2,3,5 and 6, respectively.
13. Under **Tasks** tab tap `+` → **File** → **Read File**.
14. Repeat step 8.
15. Under **To Var** type `%True` -- You can change `%True` to any other name. Make sure that you capitalize at least one letter of your variable to make it non-local. See [this](http://www.pocketables.com/2012/08/beginners-guide-to-tasker-part-2-variables.html) to know more.
16. Repeat step 11, 7 and 8.
17. Type `1` under **Text** field.
18. Repeat step 10.
19. Tap `+` corresponding to **If**. Add `%True` and `0` in fields respectively. It should look like `%True` `~` `0`.
20. Repeat step 11.
21. Under **Tasks** tab tap `+` → **Code** → **Run Shell**.
22. Type `reboot` under **Command**. (My device is rooted, so I provided root permissions to this step to avoid any hassle.) As a soft-reboot option, you can use [`killall zygote`](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43706/whats-the-best-way-to-restart-android-via-command-line-remotely/82857#82857) instead of `reboot`.
23. Check **Use Root** if your device is rooted.
24. Leave **Store Output In** and **Store Errors In** blank.
25. Repeat step 19 and 20.
26. Go to **Profiles** and enable both profiles. To save yourself from unnecessary trouble, disable any other power related profile other than the ones mentioned above.
27. [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) must be **Enabled**. You can check this by tapping Menu key/button once and amongst the options, **Disable tasker** would be visible. Also, if this app is running and you happen to minimize it, then as a default setting you would see its icon in the Status bar with the profile mentioned there (if activated).

We're good to go.

- Go to Home Screen of your device.
- Connect power source (we used USB only here).
- Your device will reboot. Do not disconnect power source to verify that boot-loop vanished.
- When the device comes back to Home Screen after reboot, you can see that **Power USB** profile is activated in tasker yet there is no boot-loop, not to mention that your initialization is also done. :)
- Disconnect power source and the profile will switch to **No power USB**.
- Connect power source again and device will reboot again for once.

**Status: Objective Completed**. Done!

Comment: It is switching between both profiles, but it doesn't execute the RunShell "reboot" task

Comment: @Tardo I traced this issue. If I uncheck **root** option in this task, then the device doesn't reboot at all. Guess what, no error in logs of Tasker as well. I checked root option and it worked fine. I'm having this feeling that your device is un-rooted.

Comment: I'm using SuperSU from Chainfire to root the device

Comment: If I execute (manually) the reboot task, it will reboot

Comment: Can you send me the screen shots of all the profiles and tasks that you made using this answer in details? IDK how to export and restore tasker data.

Comment: I will edit the post with the Profiles and Tasks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23669/discussion-between-firelord-and-tardo).

Comment: Go to the ActionBar `Settings` (in the right corner) -> `Data` -> `Share` . Then you'll be able to get into a TextEditor a file similar to the one I've just posted as an edit.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have enough reputation to use the chat. :(

Comment: No issue with chat, the system asked me so I tried moving it. Anyway, I tried viewing the stuff in text editor and I also have another option. If you hold down a profile you get the option to "Export" it. I've exported both profiles and I think you should be able to import them. I'm sending you now.

Comment: Aight. Please check the chat again.