# Temporary rooting of android device

Tags: rooting, root-access, unrooting

Recently, I was wondering if rooting needs to be a binary choice - root or no root. Can I have a phone that is unrooted, but for specific tasks, I temporarily root it, or temporarily get some privilege escalation for a specific app, and then back to unrooted either on reboot or some other way?

I was intrigued to see that there has been some discussion on such things in this stack exchange site:

- [temp root vs permanent root](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123905/what-is-the-difference-between-temp-root-pemanent-root-what-is-a-soft-reboot), where it was stated that "AT&T Samsung Galaxy Note 4 currently has temp root", but it seems a very old post
- [this answer about 4 leading root methods](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228253/is-the-root-file-different-if-a-custom-rom-is-installed) hints about "exploit based temp root methods", but it also says they are still in development or outdated

Any temp root method that somebody could point me to, that can be tried? It doesn't have to work on the latest android version, although if it does, even better.

Comment: For gaining temporary root permissions you need an vulnerable device and a matching exploit. Google and other manufacturer are fixing vulnerabilities every month, therefore what you are trying to do may be possible but it depends on your device. The older the device the higher the chance for a vulnerability you can use. But please keep in mind that everything you can do can also be done by a malicious app secretly in background. Therefore using vulnerable devices is a bit like playing with fire, the wrong app can destroy everything...

Comment: [How to manually root a phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217157/218526)

Comment: "Temporary root" is a wrong or at least vague term in my opinion. Root is root. You get the ability to run commands with UID 0, all of the (37 or more) Linux capabilities and a fully permissive SELinux context. If some capabilities are missing or SELinux context is not fully permissive, that's "incomplete root". But once you have root, it's up to you if you allow the apps to use root privileges or not. If you do, it's permanent root. If you don't it's temporary. So every rooting method can be considered permanent or temporary, depending on your choice.