# Any way to reboot device programmatically without root?

Tags: adb, root-access, reboot, device-administrator, java

I don't switch off mobile phone at night. After several weeks of uptime my mobile phone becomes slow. When I reboot it everything is smooth again.

It's not possible to root my android 5 phone, there is no custom firmware, and no current one-click-root bugs. I would like to reboot my mobile every night while charging (wireless charger), but I have not found a way to do that. I could even write an app for that if it's somehow possible.

Is there any "legal" way to reboot phone programmatically? Maybe "device administrator" app permissions can help?

Thanks

Comment: with the commandline maybe? Maybe there is something in busybox? Take a look at this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43706/whats-the-best-way-to-restart-android-via-command-line-remotely Most answers seem to require root though.

Comment: I've found a way to do so, but I don't know how to schedule it.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I can write an app to schedule. What is the way?

Comment: @POMATu On my device, I was able to execute the command `/system/bin/reboot` with a non-root user. Could you check if you're able to execute it as well?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman don't work for me, it says "permission denied".

Comment: @POMATu Annoying. Maybe the suggested answer can help, though.

Comment: take permission from makers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `AutoInput` with `Tasker`. 
AutoInput can create list with recorded screen touches for reboot, and with Tasker you can schedule action at the time you want, without root access.

Comment: But how can I reboot device from android UI? I see only "Power off" button, when I hold power button. Maybe there is button somewhere in settings?

Comment: Which Android version your phone is up to?

Comment: My android version is 5.1.1

Comment: My Samsung is using Android 5.1.1. with TouchWiz UI and it have Reboot option on Power button. See is there any way to enable Reboot option for your UI.

Comment: remotely others phone