# Android Power button shortcut

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, power-options

I am using android Marshmallow. I want to know about a shortcut method to power off my phone without power button. Without using any external emulators as explained [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36329/how-to-reboot-an-android-device-without-using-power-button). I searched it for many hours couldn't find any solution.

I like to use a solution without any app using.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Huawei GR5 and Huawei Y7 models, I found a solution using default Android settings.

Settings -> Smart Assistance -> Scheduled power on/off

There I can tell when to switch off the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you are rooted, you should be able to set up a Tasker task to do that, and then create a shortcut to that task.

In [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), click Tasks > Add new task (call it "ShutDown", or whatever) > select "System" > choose "Reboot" > set its option to "Shutdown". Then you need to give it an icon (click on the icon in the bottom right corner to do that). Now you can create a task shortcut on your home screen to that task