# Babbel languages learning apps won't play sounds

Tags: audio, troubleshooting, sony-xperia-p

The Babbel language learning app doesn't play sounds anymore; this used
to work for me for a while but now doesn't.  Sounds are the central
feature of the app which makes it superior to the PC web application, so
this is very important for me.  The Babbel support was not able to help me.

System information:

- Babbel app, version 5.2.1
- Android version 4.0.4
- Device Sony LT22i (Xperia P)
- Internal storage: 769MB free, total 1.2GB

What I tried:

- Clear the cache.  This helped for a short while but no more.
- As per advice of the Babbel team, I uninstall the Babbels apps;  then after a few minutes I re-installed again but nothing change to my sounds problems.
- Restart the device.  Like for the cache, it worked again for a short while.

The problem might be related to the size of the lesson, or the amount of speach examples, respectively.

What can I try get the sounds running again? Thank you!

Comment: If the fix is persistent, please accept the answer by pressing the checkmark below the up and down arrows to show that it worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have installed Babbel app(version 5.2.1) and it works fine on my Xolo Q1010i.

I had even tried cleaning the cache and reopening the app again, but then also it works the same way. Maybe you should try restarting your Sony LT22i and give it a try then.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Guiam Mohammed for your suggestion, i restarted by smartphone and when i tried the first two words worked, but I'm not yet sure if this will persist.

Comment: Happy to hear that vites...

Comment: You mean to say that after matching two solutions for the questions (whether you select any language to learn), your smartphone didn't provide sound for the answer Babbel App speak?

Comment: what do you mean by Babbel App speak? You mean the sounds?

Comment: Yup..I mean the sound

Comment: Sorry it takes a awhile before i answer your question, i actually tried the whole module so that i can answer you. so base on my experienced just this moment, the sounds works for a while then afterwards it stop. SO, i assume i need to switch my phone in a longer time then it might works again.

Comment: Give a try then @vites, or else you can once again download the app and then restart your smartphone. That's all what i can suggest you now.

Comment: [How to restart an Android device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1106/98922)

Comment: Restart did help, but I needed to remove the sim card and wait for a while before restarting (I switched off overnight). Now everything seems to be ok again.

Comment: Glad to hear @vites..Now enjoy learning different languages.