# Profile Question on Android Tablet

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, profiles

My background: I'm 30, my mom is 68 and terrified of technology. I gave her her first computer 2 years ago, and she's visibly terrified to use it, so I bought her a tablet for this Christmas.

Personally, I hate tablets, but I bought her a Lenovo 10" tablet running Android Jellybean 4.2.2. Now, I'm an iPhone guy, so I have never played with Android in the least. I am trying to install all the programs she will use so it's ready to go... one situation is I know she and my aunt will both want to use it to access facebook. (As horrible as this sounds,) they don't know how to change accounts; to solve this, I would like to create two profiles on the tablet.

The problem is, I don't have the "users" option in settings to let me create multiple user profiles. Does anyone know how to get around this (without Linux emu hacks)? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You don't say which Lenovo tablet you bought, but according to [this review Lenovo have disabled multiple user profiles on their Yoga 10 tablet](http://www.pocket-lint.com/review/124838-lenovo-yoga-tablet-10-review) in Android 4.2, but *may* be re-enabling the feature when they update to 4.3:

> The Lenovo Yoga Tablet launches on the Android 4.2.2 operating system,
>   which brings most of Jelly Bean's goodness - that candy-based name
>   being the generic term for Android version 4.1 to 4.3, ahead of KitKat
>   4.4's launch - but there's the notable exception for multiple user profiles. That's coming, but you'll need Android 4.3 and we don't know
>   when the Yoga Tablet will receive this update, which is already
>   available on some smart devices.

So it looks like this isn't possible on the tablet as customized by Lenovo at the moment. Why they've done this I don't know, but one common downside to manufacturer modifications and customizations to the Android OS is that they often make things look flashier but work far worse than stock Android.

One alternative is looking into loading custom ROMs that could give you back the feature, but this is a big step if you haven't done that sort of thing before, so personally I wouldn't recommend it. See these questions for more on that: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/) and [What are the advantages of a custom ROM over rooted stock?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1369/).

Alternatively, you could load a second Facebook app onto the device that has a different Facebook login saved into it. You can only load one copy of the official Facebook app on the tablet, but there are quite a [lot of third party Facebook clients out there in the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=facebook&c=apps).