# Droid X: What are the pros/cons of upgrading to Gingerbread 2.3?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, 2.3-gingerbread, updates, motorola-droid-x, stock-android

I have a Droid X running Android 2.2.1 (system version 2.3.340.MB810.Verizon.en.US).  I want to upgrade to Gingerbread 2.3 but so far I've read one positive thread where people were happy with gingerbread and the rest is doom and gloom.

I'm not really interested in doing any kind of rooting or custom ROM stuff I just want to know about the plain vanilla OTA update from Verizon (which my phone is currently asking me about).

So should I upgrade?  Or, to put it another way, what are the pros and cons of upgrading?

**EDIT**
A good answer would be like a bullet list of 5 or so negatives about Gingerbread and 5 or so positives.  A great answer would be an extensive list of the negatives and positives.  An amazing answer would add to that extensive list some anecdotal experience about the upgrade and whether they wish didn't upgrade or are glad they did and why.

I originally title this question "Droid X: Should I upgrade to Gingerbread 2.3?" but in an effort to be less subjective I've reframed the question.

Comment: Can you give any criteria?  E.g. battery life, etc.  This question is pretty open otherwise.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for this site. There isn't a specific problem to be solved here. Please review the [FAQ].

Comment: I disagree.  Reading the FAQ: "I would like others to explain to me the pros/cons of uprgrading to Gingerbread".  I think it falls under the guidelines of http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: @Al Everett: What's the difference between my question, which has been closed, and this question: [What are the pros and cons to running cyanogenmod?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-to-running-cyanogenmod)

Comment: The closure was not unilateral. While there were no close votes, it was flagged for being subjective. Normally I would suggest you vote to re-open, but I'll just go ahead and do it. Whether it stays that way is up to the community.

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak from personal experience.  I have updated my Droid X and since then I have had many issues with it.

- It seems to be unable to send texts or make calls that require a battery pull to fix.  I have to pull the battery at least once a day.
- It will not find the GPS, it is [constantly searches for GP](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=5883666146af72ef&hl=en)S.
- Any videos I had played previously through the gallery will freeze if I try to skip.  I got the Mobo player and must use Softdecoding in order to play movies where I can ski .

Some positives

- I like the darker look of the OS.
- The quick text when you are ignoring a call is very nice
- It seemed a little faster

Personally I wish I never upgraded.  I am really close to going back to 2.2, but I do not want to go through all the work involved with downgrading.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you do any of that rooting/flashing/ROM stuff or are you just on a plain vanilla phone with updates direct from Verizon?  Regarding GPS, I have that issue with my Droid X even now and I haven't upgraded.  Does the "wireless networks GPS" feature work?

Comment: @User - not rooting/flashing/ROM stuff.  I am just a plain vanilla phone with updates from Verizon.

Answer (score 1):

Now, to be fair, I never took the official OTA, I was on the leaked gingerbread back in April (or maybe March, I forget).  I never saw a reason to go to the official build.  And now I'm running CM7, which has it's own set of customisations.

Anyway, the downsides from what I've seen (remember that this was an early build):

- It seemed like there was less memory to go around.  I would often listen to a podcast while playing a game on Froyo.  Occasionally, in gingerbread, the audio from the podcast would just stop, and I would notice that Android ran out of RAM, and killed google listen.
- I found certain bits of the UI to be a bit ugly, namely that menu items where black, but the background if there wasn't a menu was white.  This was really jarring for apps that used listviews as their main interface, expecting black on black, or at least two matching colors.

And now some good things:

- It certainly seemed much faster than froyo.  But to be fair, I jumped from the leaked froyo from back in August, to this version of gingerbread.
- The built in launcher seemed like it was almost usable (as opposed to the launcher in Froyo and Eclair).  However, I still put ADW on top of it.
- More APIs obviously.  While as a consumer you probably won't use it, developers will.  And while there's not too many gingerbread specific stuff out yet, it's coming.  I especially see Game Devs using it more and more, now that they can make games entirely in C/C++, and don't have to touch Java at all.

I never had any problems with the GPS, calling, or texting, like David Basarab seems to have, but I guess those could be side effects of either an app he had installed, or just that he was on a later build than me.