# Are there good resources for comparing performance of Stock Motorola ROMs vs. CM7.1?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, motorola-droid-x, performance

I'm looking for a good resource for which shows performance comparison - for Droid X - of Froyo 2.2 (stock ROM), Gingerbread 2.3 (Stock Verizon ROM) and any sort of Cyanogen ROM running on Droid X (presumably 2.3 based - 7.1?)

I'm NOT looking for first-person subjective accounts like [these](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11643/droid-x-what-are-the-pros-cons-of-upgrading-to-gingerbread-2-3).

I'm looking for benchmarks - either as a direct single benchmark using identical set of installed apps; or better yet a set of collated averaged statistics.

I'm mainly interested in "normal business use" performance, not intensive graphics games one - I don't play anything heavier than Angry Birds. So if there is data from different benchmarks, whichever one approximates everyday business use would be preferred.

I would ideally like something which covers all 3 ROMs listed above (stock 2.2, stock 2.3 and CM7) but will be happy with any answers that only show pairwise comparisons of any 2.

**NOTE:** While the question is specifically about Droid X, I will accept an answer which shows a very good comparison of performance that illustrates a clear difference between ROMs across ALL comparable hardware (e.g. 1Ghz single-core, 512Mb memory, PowerVR SGX530 or comparable GPU) and makes a case that the difference should be easily carried over to DX.

---

*Background:* I am considering upgrading my Droid X from Froyo 2.2 (stock, rooted) to Gingerbread. I need to choose to either spend the time figuring out how to load the not-officially-supported CM7 from nightlies, or simply loading Verizon's stock Gingerbread ROM.

The 3 main things I'm concerned about as far as choosing ROM are (1) Stability, (2) Memory footprint, (3) Performance. This question only covers #3.

Comment: @Chance - 1. [Quadrant](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard&hl=en) is a standard Android benchmarking application; 2. While I appreciate the spirit, comments to the tune "I don't know about this" are not very helpful and shouldn't be added.

Comment: honestly, All I have seen are first person accounts. I mean that is pretty much what a review is.

Answer (score 3):

One baseline for measuring phone performance is the [Quadrant Score](http://smartphonebenchmarks.com/forum/index.php?/topic/23-about-quadrant-standard-edition/).

[Here](http://pocketnow.com/android/droid-x-quadrant-scores-nearly-double-after-gingerbread-update) is the quadrant score for Droid X with FroYo and Gingerbread.

[This site](http://smartphonebenchmarks.com/index.php?filter_model=Motorola%20Droid%20X&filter_benchmarkapp=Quadrant&filter_cpu=all&filter_gpu=all) shows various quadrant scores for the Droid X with CM7, as well as unofficial versions of Gingerbread and FroYo.

There are [some debates](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/hacking-help/73582-what-exactly-significance-these-benchmark-quadrant-scores-whatever.html) about the usefulness of the Quadrant Score - hopefully since these are comparisons with the same model of phone, they would be useful.

Comment: The second link would be great if only there was at least ONE score for CM7 with zero overclocking :(   Not your fault, +1 for great answer