# How can I execute command in the terminal as root?

Tags: root-access, terminal

How can I get root permissions in a terminal?

Answer (score 17):

Type `su` and your terminal prompt should change from `$` to `#`. This is assuming that your device is already rooted.

Comment: AND that su is installed.

Comment: i try it but this message shown "permission denide"

Comment: @mahdi: Is your device already rooted?

Comment: no i try it on emulator

Comment: is it possible to do root on emulator ?

Comment: 'Permission denied' usually means the command or program itself is does not have permissions for execution. Use chmod to set the permissions of the file (Google it) and then run

Comment: @HXCaine: If you don't have permission to run `su`, you probably don't have permission to `chmod` it.

Comment: Works, thanks! On FairPhone this will cause the OS to prompt allow SuperUser privileges for the used shell. Approving this will yield a shell in SU-mode. I used [Terminal Emulator](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdcategory=System&fdid=jackpal.androidterm&fdpage=9)

Comment: Thanks, that was super helpful. (`su` seems to work by default in the Android x86 iso.)

Answer (score 3):

See the following questions:

- [What does "to root a phone" mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236/what-does-to-root-a-phone-mean)
- [How do I root my phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone)
- [I've rooted my phone.  Now what?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1/ive-rooted-my-phone-now-what)

Comment: But how does this address the question?

Answer (score 1):

Production phones don't ship with root access, developer phones do. If you have a production phone (likely: you'd know if you bought a dev phone), you have to "root" them first. As @Joe_Casadonte points out, there are some great instructions here and elsewhere (Notably the CyanogenMod Wiki and Android Rom's google group) to get you started rooting your phone. (And if you get stuck ... come back here with your questions!).

Once you've rooted your phone, you can gain root privileges in the adb shell or the terminal emulator with the `su` command.

Note: it sounds from some of your responses like you haven't yet rooted your phone. So you'll need to start there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

1. Your Android device is rooted;
2. The `su` binary is located at `/system/xbin/su`;
3. The shell binary is located at `/system/bin/sh`; and
4. Your Android device has [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) installed.

If all the 4 conditions above are satisfied, then:

- If you want to enter the shell and become root (superuser uid 0) so you can execute commands without uid restrictions, start the Terminal Emulator app and just execute this command:

  ```
  su -
  ```

  In order to disconnect from the uid 0 (exit superuser status), press <kbd>Volume -</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd>, or type `exit` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Alternatively, if you want to **always** start Terminal Emulator as root, then start Terminal Emulator, go to **Preferences**, scroll down to the **SHELL** section, tap the **Command line** option and modify the command so it becomes this:

  ```
  /system/xbin/su -c "/system/bin/sh -"
  ```

  After you change the command, exit Terminal Emulator (close the application) and start it again. Notice how Terminal Emulator's shell interface now shows you `root@something` by default.

Answer (score 0):

For my 8.1.0 go edition phone. It is `/sbin/su -c "/system/bin/sh -"`. I struggle too much to figure out where is `su` binary file(in my case `su` binary not exist in the `/system/xbin/` path). I found a path `/sbin/` is exist in ROOT directory and `su` binary is exist in that path. And of course i rooted my phone by magisk manager. Hope this answer will help someone.