# Ice Cream Sandwich (ICS) - Encryption, select different PIN than Screen Lock

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, encryption, password

I was wondering if one can select different passwords for device encryption in ICS?

Having the same password for encryption and unlocking the screen isn't quite that secure...

Thanks for hints.

Answer (score 3):

No. A quote from http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1663755:

> Note that this is the same PIN or password that you use to unlock your phone without encryption, and cannot be set independently.

EDIT: I found this on xda, but I think it might be risky and not worth the effort.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1680857

Answer (score 1):

For phones that are *already* encrypted, the Android 5.x (Lollipop) the command has changed somewhat. Now instead of typing in the password in quotes, you must first encode the password as hexadecimal and issue the following commands after obtaining root:

```
vdc cryptfs changepw password HEX_ENCODED_PASSWORD_HERE
```

Because the password is hex encoded, the resulting value doesn't need quotes surrounding it.

The other command mentioned `vdc cryptfs changepw 'plaintext password here'` has no effect on Android 5.x and later releases.

If I were to change my password to `testing`, I would issue this command after obtaining root:

```
vdc cryptfs changepw password 74657374696e67
```

If I wanted to change my password to something more exotic (which included special characters, quotes, and other punctuation e.g. `What's up "Doc"?` I would issue the following command in the `adb shell` after obtaining `su` root:

```
vdc cryptfs changepw password 5768617427732075702022446f63223f
```

Now reboot the phone (you can issue a `reboot` command) and you'll be prompted for the new password.

If the device is not currently encrypted at all, you would issue the following command:

```
vdc cryptfs enablecrypto inplace HEX_ENCODED_PASSWORD_HERE
```

The phone will reboot itself automatically and being the encryption process which could take an hour or more.

Answer (score 0):

[EncPassChanger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kibab.android.EncPassChanger) claims to do this, haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 0):

The encryption password does not have the be the same as the screen unlock PIN. In fact, you can encrypt your device with a password without having any screen locking password/PIN at all. (this was initially the case with my newly installed device).

If you think of a possible secure implementation it makes sense. The encryption passphrase is not directly used to encrypt your data. First, a key derivation function is applied to the passphrase. The resulting key is then used to encrypt the master key. (This master key is used for disk encryption.)

Changing the master key is not possible without re-encrypting all data which takes quite some time. What is possible, and much faster, is changing the passphrase that protects the master key. Unlike the GPLv2-licensed [LUKS](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/) software, you can only specify one passphrase.

Requirements:

- Superuser privileges.
- Either a terminal application on your device or a computer which has `adb`.
- [A good passphrase](https://xkcd.com/936/).

Instructions:

1. Enter the shell. This can be done by opening the Terminal app or by running `adb shell` on your computer. (see also 2)
2. [Obtain root privileges](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4021/17994) by running `su`
3. Assuming your password to be `Give Mom batteries`, execute the following command:

   ```
   vdc cryptfs changepw 'Give Mom batteries'
   ```

   If you have chose exotic characters for your passphrase, be sure to properly [escape](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html) those.
4. The passphrase has immediately changed, replacing the old one. You can reboot to check it yourself.

I found these arguments by looking in the source code of vold, in particular [CommandListener.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/android-4.2.2_r1.2/CommandListener.cpp). This command has always been available since the introduction of disk encryption in ICS:

```
$git log -n1 --oneline 70a4b3fd7a84a84bbe6e9d6d4ca3ee2098259fd 
70a4b3f Change cryptfs changepw to only require a new password.
$ git branch --contains 70a4b3fd7a84a84bbe6e9d6d4ca3ee2098259fd -a
* cm-10.1
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/cm-10.1
  remotes/origin/cm-10.1
  remotes/origin/cm-9.0.0
  remotes/origin/cm-9.1.0
  remotes/origin/ics
  remotes/origin/ics-release
  remotes/origin/jellybean
  remotes/origin/jellybean-stable
  remotes/origin/mr1.1-staging
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are able to set a different password for device encryption to the one you choose for screen unlock.

Comment: What evidence do you have for this? Yes/No answers aren't very helpful without any "How" element.