# How to set a better encryption password

Tags: lock-screens, 4.4-kitkat, encryption, nexus-5

How would I go about setting a stronger password for disk encryption on my android device?

I had set a PIN already before enabling full disk encryption, and it proceeded to use that PIN as the decryption string when the device boots.

I understand that switching my PIN / Password will update the decryption string as well, but entering a password every time I unlock the phone is a serious inconvenience. Similarly using a short integer to encrypt the disk leaves it much easier to decrypt.

How do I go about setting a better decryption password, while keeping my PIN? I have no interest in solutions that require rooting the device.

Comment: `I have no interest in solutions that require rooting the device.` -> Pretty sure that you're stuck, then. You can follow [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29468) on the Android bug tracker if you want, but there's no native way to do what you're looking for without root, as far as I know.

Comment: Probably relevant: [Ice Cream Sandwich (ICS) - Encryption, select different PIN than Screen Lock](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17292/ice-cream-sandwich-ics-encryption-select-different-pin-than-screen-lock)