# Permission denied when I run insmod in terminal emulator

Tags: nexus-one, root-access, terminal, file-permissions

I want to install a module (bcm4329.ko) in my nexus one phone. I have rooted the phone and installed Cyanogenmod too.

In Terminal emulator, I tried various commands but everything resulted in failure

```
$ insmod /system/lib/modules/bcm4329.ko //[Operation Not Permitted]
$ su insmod /system/lib/modules/bcm4329.ko //[throw the syntax/man page of su]
$ cd /system/lib/modules
$ chmod 777 bcm4329.ko //[Read only file system]
```

The error messages I received are enclosed within '[ ]' after every command. How can I install this module in my android phone. Any help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remount the system partition as read-write, it's read-only by default.

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

Comment: Got the error "mount: permission denied (are you root?)" Is there any other way to give root permission, as I already have rooted the device.

Comment: @SyncMaster Did you type `su` in the terminal first?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4021/how-to-be-root-user-in-terminal solved it. thanks. :)

Comment: @SyncMaster Lol good timing.