# Rooted Incredible WiFi Tethering Not Working

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

I've rooted my Droid Incredible and installed both the "Wireless Tether" and "Barnacle Wifi Tether" apps but I can't seem to get internet connectivity on any other devices. I can see the connection on my laptop and on my iPad and my devices get ip addresses assigned to them but I can't connect to the internet. Google Chrome reports "Name unresolved" while Safari on the iPad only states that the device isn't connected to the internet. Why isn't this working?

Comment: Are "Wireless Tether" and "Barnacle Wifi Tether" designed for the Incredible?

Comment: @Matthew Read They weren't specifically designed for it, as far as I know. Wireless Tether was given as an answer to this question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1/ive-rooted-my-phone-now-what/13#13 so I'm assuming (bad practice, I know) that it should be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you download Wireless Tether from the Market or from http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/ ?

If you are running Android 2.1 you need to take the extra steps listed here:
http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/wiki/Setup_HTC_Desire_Incredible

If you are running 2.2 then in theory it should just work.

I would first try the latest release candidate here:
http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/downloads/detail?name=wireless_tether_2_0_5-RC2.apk&can=2&q=

Let me know how it works out.

Comment: Latest release candidate did it. Thank you so much!