# Can I create a WiFi hotspot using Incredible HTC phone?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, wifi-hotspot

I'd like to create a WiFi hotspot using my Incredible HTC phone.  What software do I need to add to do this or can it be done with the built-in software?

Comment: Similar: [Rooted Incredible WiFi Tethering Not Working](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4084/rooted-incredible-wifi-tethering-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What software do I need to add to do this or can it be done with the built-in software?

All software for it is built-in. Look through `Setting->Wireless & networks` menu. There must be items like `Portable Wi-Fi hotspot` and `Portable Wi-Fi hotspot settings`

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by rooting the phone and installing CyanogenMod 7.  The WiFi hotspot for tethering other devices is built into the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

If your OS version is 2.2 or above you will have the option by default in the settings.

```
Setting->Wireless & networks->Tethering & portable hotspot-> Tick Portable hotspot.
```