# How can I tell if I have root?

Tags: root-access

I've been attempting to root my phone (Samsung Intercept M910, but that probably doesn't matter).

How can I tell that I have actually, successfully gained root? I've run a few apps which require root, and some work and some don't, so I'm unclear if I've gained root or not.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use terminal emulator (a popular free/open-source terminal emulator is [Android Terminal Emulator](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator#readme), available from [F-droid](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=terminal&fdid=jackpal.androidterm) or [Play Market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)), open the emulator and type

`su`

you will know with the message that appears after if phone is rooted or not.

Edit:

There is an app just for this now : [Root Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck)

Comment: A popular free/open-source terminal emulator is [Android Terminal Emulator](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator#readme), available from [F-droid](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=terminal&fdid=jackpal.androidterm) or [Play Market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm).

Comment: What if "su: not found"? It simply implies that the `su` utility has not been installed (or is not in the PATH), rather than whether we have root...

Comment: I got "su: not found". But I still suspect the phone is rooted. What can I do now?

Comment: try this app :  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck

Answer (score 29):

Connect your phone in developer mode via USB and start an ADB shell

```
adb shell
```

If you see a `#` at the beginning of the line your phone is rooted, if it's a `$` try to execute the `su` command, and if you get a `#` now, your phone is rooted, but if you get an error that `su` can't be found it's probably not, or the `su` binary is simply missing.

There are also [apps on the market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck) that test if your phone is rooted.

Comment: That's not enough. If you see a "$"-Prompt you still can elevate to root via the su binary (typing the "su" command), if you have successfully rooted your phone.

Comment: Yeah, forgot that some ROMs doesn't have root as default. Hm, anything else you want me to change now?

Answer (score 8):

There is an application available in the market called [Root Checker](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck), that can verify if your phone is rooted, and if you have BusyBox installed.

Comment: Does not that just check for the su binary?

Comment: That is exactly what it means to be "rooted", is to have su binary installed properly with suid bit set. The su binary commonly comes with an accompaniment program to manage permissions, Superuser app, but this is just for conveniences and ease of use.

Comment: Thanks @Lie Ryan, but from some other comments it looks like the phone can still be rooted even if there is no su binary. Is that not correct?

Comment: Please see this thread for the reason I am asking: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127347/can-gmail-be-uninstalled-on-android-5-1-1-lollipop

Comment: @Leo: to be precise, there isn't exactly a different state between rooted and unrooted devices in the underlying Linux system. All Linuxes, including unrooted Android, have setuid system call, which is the primary mechanisms used by Linux programs to acquire elevated privilege. Setting up a suid binary itself requires elevated privilege. Many Android system applications on a unrooted device runs with elevated privilege (e.g. adbd, system updater), but they only escalate for very specific purposes. su is a privileged program that allows you to invoke other programs with elevated privileged.

Comment: Thanks @Lie Ryan, that was what I thought. But I am trying to understand what the trouble is with my phone (if any, how could Gmail be uninstalled?). As I understand it Gmail can be uninstalled on a rooted Android, but I do not understand exactly why - or should I say "how"? I mean can I on rooted device just uninstall Gmail from the Play Store app, or?

Comment: @Leo: in short, being rooted is actually a property of a running process, not the system/device. If a process runs with elevated privilege, they're running as root, this is irrespective of whether su is installed. What "rooted device" in common Android parlance means is that the device is set up so that the user can elevate privilege of arbitrary programs, which is achieved by installing su as a suid program.

Comment: I see, @Lie Ryan. So, perhaps, in my case a possibility is that the Play Store app has the setuid bit set (or what it is called on Android)? Is there any way to check this?

Answer (score 5):

You should see the "Superuser" application in the app tray.

Most rooting methods add this app to manage the superuser rights: it appeared for me when I rooted my Desire.

Comment: You can install Superuser on a non-rooted device just fine, though. It just won't do anything without the `su` binary (and will complain that it needs to "update" it every time you run it). The presence of Superuser doesn't really mean you're rooted; running it kind of does, but the update failure message doesn't say "failed to update because you're not root" or anything of that nature (and you can hit "Cancel" and it goes away).

Answer (score 1):

Beside what everyone mentioned,
One super easy way would also be installing an app from Google Play that requires root access.
I suggest DroidWall, which is a must-have firewall for android. Install it, and hit apply rules. If not rooted, it will tell you, and will fail to apply rule.

Answer (score 0):

For developers and to provide an *imho* more comprising test via `adb` do the following:

```
[you@yourbox]$ adb shell
[root&adbshell]$ mount -o rw,remount /system
[root&adbshell]$ echo $?
 0
[root&adbshell]$
[root&adbshell]$ mount | grep system
 /dev/block/by-name/system /system ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
[root&adbshell]$ ls /dev/block/by-name/system -la  
 lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2016-02-23 19:33 system -> /dev/block/nandd
[root&adbshell]$ ls /dev/block/nandd -la 
 brw------- root     root      93,  24 2016-02-23 19:33 nandd
```

points are that :

1. Chances are that the adb shell prompt will tell you `root@[something]` which is clear
2. but just to check we try remounting `/system` read-write `rw` (something that needs root)
3. checking that the result worked out i.e no error `echo $?` yields `0`
4. then still checking / following that `/system` eventually was at a block device `/dev/block/nandd` in the example that is reported to be accessible only by `root`

I am aware that this is a "for advanced users only" option, and ad best similar to [the other answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/13336/152874) suggested by @kyrias, but I think this one is slighly more compatible as `mount` in contrast to `su` is more likely to be there.

Also I would like to suggest that a comprehensive test of `rootness` would involve now to use the `root` powers and backup the content of the /system and flash it with an alternative system for trial. Else there **is a change** the adbd is only faking you information, always better to make sure you can test `root` powers by actually doing something that is visible on multiple channels :)

Answer (score 0):

You can download an application called **"Root Checker"** that gains root access to your device and tests if it's rooted or not. You can easily understand with that way if it's rooted or not. I can understand with that way and it's extremely easy.

There are a lot of applications called Root Checker but that doesn't matter just install one and you're good to go.

After doing that you can understand is it rooted or not.

If it's rooted you can use every application that requires root with the device you're using.

If you're device is not rooted open the recovery project you've installed **(on Samsung devices press the volume down+power+home button at the same time)** and from there wipe the data. Then reboot your phone from the main menu of the recovery project and press volume up+power+home button to open the download menu.

**WARNING: THE METHOD EXPLAINED HERE ONLY WORKS WITH EVERY SAMSUNG PHONE. AND IT WILL NOT WORK WITH OTHERS. IT CAN WORK BUT NOT SURE ABOUT IT. YOU CAN FIND MORE INFORMATION ABOUT THIS CASE ON OTHER WEBSITES.**

Connect your device to your Windows Computer and using Odin you can flash the necessary files including SuperSU to the device. And after doing those just reboot and bang, your device is rooted successfully.

**Max Lee can help you on his website (highonandroid.com) that prepares cool articles about rooting.**

**You can also prefer The Unlockr that you can find on youtube and theunlockr.com.**

Both prefer nice videos that can be helpful to you.

Answer (score -1):

Its easy. Just download some famous root requiring apps(apps which require root) eg:- titanium backup, supersu etc. and see that they work or not. If they work correctly, then you have gained root. If they don't work, it means root is not working.

Comment: If they don't work, that might also have other reasons – such as incompatibilities with your device, bugs in the app. Of course if all of them fail, that might be a strong indicator – but a long way to go. Using a [root checker](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/13339/16575), or a [terminal app](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/13349/16575) (as suggested in the linked answers) are much faster and more reliable methods.

Comment: Checking root is also a good method but according to question details, some apps had worked and some had not so probably root checker can also fail

Comment: It's more likely those failed for a different reason: A root-checker, or especially running the `su` command, has much less complexity, and thus is much less likely to fail.

Comment: Yes, you should download root checker basic or pro.