# Problem installing ubuntu on Galaxy S2 ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, linux

The Error:

when running the ubuntu install script (ubuntu.sh) I get:

```
ubuntu.sh[11]:cut not found
This script requires root! Type:su
```

what I have done so far:

Installed a custom kernel that roots the phone:

[KERNEL] SpeedMod SGS2 ICS [K3-16 CIFS ROOT / NO-ROOT CWM5]

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1574218

I installed it using Odin using the following instructions:

http://touristinparadise.blogspot.com/2010/11/samsung-galaxy-s-how-to-install.html

that all seemed to go fine.

Installed "Ubuntu Installer Free" from market place.

I then installed busybox:

tried Stephen (Stericson) and JRummy16 apps from market place.

I installed the VNC viewer as recommended by Ubuntu installer app.

I also installed Android Terminal Emulator (Jack Palevich)  as recomended by Ubuntu installer app.

Downloaded and de-compressed the image and script as per links from Ubuntu installer app.

I decompressed them to my external card initially but then moved them to the "internal" sdcard folder.

I also tried to establish that I had loopback device capability.. I found this thread:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1425888

And the folders mentioned are present.

I think that is all i have done so far ;-)..

I had a look at the script and the failing line and it seems to me if the "cut" command was not found then it would report that i didnt have su privelages even if i did.

I have many times ofer forgotten and approved su access for terminal emulator and busybox..

When I type su in the terminal emulator the symbol for text entry changes from `$ to`# ..

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `su` from the terminal first, then run `ubuntu.sh` again.

Comment: I am running su (I think)  how can I test that it is working?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13335/how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-root/13349#13349

Answer (score 0):

Open the script up using an app, such as root explorer, and add the line `su` to the beginning, and try again.