# How do I know if my device is rooted?

Tags: root-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell if I have root?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13335/how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-root)

I am a noob when it comes to android.

I've read a little about rooting, but I still haven't figured out how to know if my device is already rooted or not (I bought it from a questionable store, so I don't want to just take their word for it).

I have a Galaxy S2, but I think this question is relevant for any android device.

Comment: I searched for a question covering this topic before I posted, but somehow I missed it. Sorry...

Comment: Don't worry - posting a duplicate is really not a bad thing unless the title and content of your post are really quite identical to the original (in which case a search should find it). Having duplicates with different wording will ultimately catch more search terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best way to test would be to install an app that requires root access to perform it's main functions. Like [ROM Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager&hl=en), [Wi-Fi Tether](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=android.tether&hl=en) or most [screenshot apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidscreenshotapptool.free&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwiY29tLmFuZHJvaWRzY3JlZW5zaG90YXBwdG9vbC5mcmVlIl0.). They will require root and notify you if you do not have root access.

Comment: if you have adb access, you can go to "adb shell". if you see # on command line then you are rooted, $ if not.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have application like superuser or superSU installed, and launched it.
you'll see.